# How do I bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a few checkboxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' value="apple" checked>
<input type='checkbox' value="orange">
<input type='checkbox' value="pear" checked>
<input type='checkbox' value="naartjie">
```

That I would like to bind to a list in my controller such that whenever a checkbox is changed the controller maintains a list of all the checked values, for example, `['apple', 'pear']`.

ng-model seems to only be able to bind the value of one single checkbox to a variable in the controller.

Is there another way to do it so that I can bind the four checkboxes to a list in the controller?

Comment: Does it have to be a list?  Would an object work?: `<input type='checkbox' ng-model="checkboxes.apple">`, etc.  Model would be:{"apple":true,"orange":false,"pear":true,"naartjie":true}

Comment: Try the directive in this [Repo](https://github.com/Vikasg7/checkbox-select)

Comment: Be sure to look past the accepted answer. There's [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16599233/199712) which is, in my opinion, much more elegant.

Comment: `naartjie` !? That just gives you away boet! :D

Comment: @ppumkin hehe just seen this. You're right :D

Comment: @All can you please check similar question I cant able to solve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573515/how-to-populate-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs#51573623

Comment: Hahaha leka man!

Answer (score 953, accepted):

There are two ways to approach this problem. Either use a simple array or an array of objects. Each solution has it pros and cons. Below you'll find one for each case.

---

#### With a simple array as input data

The HTML could look like:

```
<label ng-repeat="fruitName in fruits">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="selectedFruits[]"
    value="{{fruitName}}"
    ng-checked="selection.indexOf(fruitName) > -1"
    ng-click="toggleSelection(fruitName)"
  > {{fruitName}}
</label>
```

And the appropriate controller code would be:

```
app.controller('SimpleArrayCtrl', ['$scope', function SimpleArrayCtrl($scope) {

  // Fruits
  $scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'naartjie'];

  // Selected fruits
  $scope.selection = ['apple', 'pear'];

  // Toggle selection for a given fruit by name
  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(fruitName) {
    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(fruitName);

    // Is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    // Is newly selected
    else {
      $scope.selection.push(fruitName);
    }
  };
}]);
```

**Pros**: Simple data structure and toggling by name is easy to handle

**Cons**: Add/remove is cumbersome as two lists (the input and selection) have to be managed

---

#### With an object array as input data

The HTML could look like:

```
<label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <!--
    - Use `value="{{fruit.name}}"` to give the input a real value, in case the form gets submitted
      traditionally

    - Use `ng-checked="fruit.selected"` to have the checkbox checked based on some angular expression
      (no two-way-data-binding)

    - Use `ng-model="fruit.selected"` to utilize two-way-data-binding. Note that `.selected`
      is arbitrary. The property name could be anything and will be created on the object if not present.
  -->
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="selectedFruits[]"
    value="{{fruit.name}}"
    ng-model="fruit.selected"
  > {{fruit.name}}
</label>
```

And the appropriate controller code would be:

```
app.controller('ObjectArrayCtrl', ['$scope', 'filterFilter', function ObjectArrayCtrl($scope, filterFilter) {

  // Fruits
  $scope.fruits = [
    { name: 'apple',    selected: true },
    { name: 'orange',   selected: false },
    { name: 'pear',     selected: true },
    { name: 'naartjie', selected: false }
  ];

  // Selected fruits
  $scope.selection = [];

  // Helper method to get selected fruits
  $scope.selectedFruits = function selectedFruits() {
    return filterFilter($scope.fruits, { selected: true });
  };

  // Watch fruits for changes
  $scope.$watch('fruits|filter:{selected:true}', function (nv) {
    $scope.selection = nv.map(function (fruit) {
      return fruit.name;
    });
  }, true);
}]);
```

**Pros**: Add/remove is very easy

**Cons**: Somewhat more complex data structure and toggling by name is cumbersome or requires a helper method

---

**Demo**: http://jsbin.com/ImAqUC/1/

Comment: FYI, instead of injecting $filter, you can inject filterFilter, and then use as follows:  return filterFilter($scope.fruits, {checked: true});  Built-in and custom filters are registered with the $injector with name filterNameFilter ("filterName" should be in italics) -- [$filterProvider docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$filterProvider)

Comment: `value="{{fruit.name}}"` and `ng-checked="fruit.checked"` are superfluous, since ng-model is used.

Comment: @MarkRajcok you're right in both cases. Though I'll leave the answer as is, for maybe the different usages will help somebody. And the more general `$filter` allows using more than one filter inside the controller (at least without injecting each seperatly).

Comment: I noticed that there is no need to specify "checked" in the model, Angular will set the property automatically :)

Comment: This answer is not what the initial question was about. The author wanted to generate a list of checked boxes.

Comment: @Steren issn't `{{fruits | filter:{checked:true} }}` exactly that?

Comment: @Yoshi I meant, the author wanted to get an array of the checked boxes  like ['apple', 'pear'], not an object containing 'name' and 'checked'.

Comment: Should use ng-change instead of ng-click because it deals with edge cases better.

Comment: You can also bind a getter/setter function, sort of like double binding an expression. It's down here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26741697/719141

Comment: @amccausl that doesn't work, because ng-model is not present.

Comment: How does `$scope.selectedFruits` select the checkbox?

Comment: @Marty.H It doesn't. `ng-model` (angular) handles the selection.

Comment: When I uncheck the selectbox it sends that checkbox value to the server with false. How can I prevent that ?
Eg:  {"brand_features":{"1":false,"2":false,"3":true}}

Comment: I can't make out what `name="selectedFruits[]"` does? @Yoshi could you please advice?

Comment: @ViktorMolokostov That would just be useful, if you were to submit the form *traditionally*. Meaning posting it to the action handler (some server side script). With php, a form element with a name like that (using the square brackets) creates an array in the request data. This way you could easily handle the selected fruits.

Comment: @Yoshi, thanks. I just got confused with `$scope.selectedFruits` and `name=selectedFruits[]` attribute names. I was wondering that it might be another angular html dialect feature I'm not aware of. Thanks again!

Comment: Please see this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38194899/4850220) by me to see the better implementation of the idea by @yoshi.

Comment: @VikasGautam Now that's a very opinionated statement posed as a fact...

Comment: @Yoshi - "naartjie" - haven't seen that word in a long time :)

Comment: when i have use "With a simple array as input data", it gives me null values in json.

Answer (score 416):

A simple solution:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <label ng-repeat="(color,enabled) in colors">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="colors[color]" /> {{color}} 
  </label>
  <p>colors: {{colors}}</p>
</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
      $scope.colors = {Blue: true, Orange: true};
  });
</script>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/U4VD61?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, I was also following the way where things must be convenient :)

Comment: @kolypto - this is definitely the answer. I rewrote it for people (like me) who are working with objects: http://plnkr.co/edit/cqsADe8lKegsBMgWMyB8?p=preview

Comment: I do it just as you do, but what does the enabled in `(color,enabled) in colors` do?

Comment: @Sebastian, since `colors` is an object, when you iterate it -- you get pairs of `(key,value)`.

Comment: Oh yes, I'm using an Array of Objects so I don't need this (like in Yoshi's answer). So I was using a conclusion of your and Yoshi's answer :-D. +1 both ;-)

Comment: Though I like this answer very much! I think, there is one major problem with using objects as data source. That is, because by definition the order of objects properties is undefined, one can't provide a definite order when displaying the checkboxes. Still +1 ;)

Comment: @Yoshi you can just make `colors` in this case an array so order is defined. Same general concept can be used...

Comment: I got this: for 3 checkboxes, [1:true] when only the middle one checked, [true, false] when only the first one checked, [false,false,true] when the last one checked. it's a little weird to work with.

Comment: Just wish you wouldn't use Plunker - so damn slow

Comment: `colors` should be named `isSelected`, it is much easier to read `isSelected[color]` than `colors[color]`

Comment: A little problem with this solution is that we are not in control of the order, that is it is oredered alphabetically. But its short and simple. Like it

Comment: This solution is better than the other. I used this simple solution to dynamically display or hide columns of a grid.

Comment: It there a way to make it as an array, instead of an object?

Comment: Note that without a name or id on the html elements this will not cooperate with a form and form validation.

Answer (score 88):

```
<input type='checkbox' ng-repeat="fruit in fruits"
  ng-checked="checkedFruits.indexOf(fruit) != -1" ng-click="toggleCheck(fruit)">
```

.

```
function SomeCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = ["apple, orange, pear, naartjie"];
    $scope.checkedFruits = [];
    $scope.toggleCheck = function (fruit) {
        if ($scope.checkedFruits.indexOf(fruit) === -1) {
            $scope.checkedFruits.push(fruit);
        } else {
            $scope.checkedFruits.splice($scope.checkedFruits.indexOf(fruit), 1);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Love how simple this is, exactly what I am looking for (although I have to admit that @vitalets directive is amazing). I have modified Umur's code a little to create this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/9mwsbfuc/

Comment: I make the words of the Samurai Jane mine! How simple it was to show just what I needed! :)

Answer (score 81):

Here's a quick little reusable directive that seems to do what you're looking to do. I've simply called it `checkList`. It updates the array when the checkboxes change, and updates the checkboxes when the array changes.

```javascript
app.directive('checkList', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      list: '=checkList',
      value: '@'
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      var handler = function(setup) {
        var checked = elem.prop('checked');
        var index = scope.list.indexOf(scope.value);

        if (checked && index == -1) {
          if (setup) elem.prop('checked', false);
          else scope.list.push(scope.value);
        } else if (!checked && index != -1) {
          if (setup) elem.prop('checked', true);
          else scope.list.splice(index, 1);
        }
      };

      var setupHandler = handler.bind(null, true);
      var changeHandler = handler.bind(null, false);

      elem.bind('change', function() {
        scope.$apply(changeHandler);
      });
      scope.$watch('list', setupHandler, true);
    }
  };
});
```

Here's a controller and a view that shows how you might go about using it.

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MainController'>
  <span ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
    <input type='checkbox' value="{{fruit}}" check-list='checked_fruits'> {{fruit}}<br />
  </span>

  <div>The following fruits are checked: {{checked_fruits | json}}</div>

  <div>Add fruit to the array manually:
    <button ng-repeat="fruit in fruits" ng-click='addFruit(fruit)'>{{fruit}}</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```javascript
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'naartjie'];
  $scope.checked_fruits = ['apple', 'pear'];
  $scope.addFruit = function(fruit) {
    if ($scope.checked_fruits.indexOf(fruit) != -1) return;
    $scope.checked_fruits.push(fruit);
  };
});
```

(The buttons demonstrate that changing the array will also update the checkboxes.)

Finally, here is an example of the directive in action on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3YNLsyoG4PIBW6Kj7dRK?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Brandon, this did exactly what I wanted (and exactly what the question asked for too, unlike the other answers). The only tweak I made was to change your "elem.on('change', function() ..." to "elem.bind('change', function()..." so as to remove the dependency on jQuery.

Comment: This is pretty neat, but somehow destroys my ability to use ng-disabled :( Is there any way I can fix that?

Comment: Super useful!  And even worked for me with objects instead of arrays for both the source list and the data list!

Comment: I agree with everyone. This one is the most useful and undoubtedly reusable one!! Thanks for the good work. :)

Comment: If you are having problems with AngularJS >= 1.4.4, check https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13037: replace `value: '@'` by `value: '=ngValue'`

Comment: `bind` to add an event listener **_is_** jQuery-ish; it's one of a limited selection of jQuery methods Angular's jqLite implements. Less than ideal now, since `on` has been the jQuery recommendation since Nov 2011 (`bind` remains for backward-compatibility). `on` is preferable for reasons including being distinguished from JS's `bind`. `bind` _does_ enable "removing the jQuery dependency", in terms of "**_full_** jQuery", so it's valuable, _but_ while in 2013 `bind` helped support IE8, post-1.3 (Oct 2014) there's little or no benefit to using jqLite `bind` over the standard `addEventListener`.

Comment: Note that you may run into trouble if you are working with integers: `value` will be cast to string, and `Array.indexOf()` uses strict comparison, so it will try to populate the target list with string versions of your source integers. My solution was to add a secondary, optional `check-integer` attribute, which (if present) will force the `handler` to `parseInt(scope.value, 10)` before passing it to `indexOf` and `push`.

Answer (score 67):

Based on answers in this thread I've created [checklist-model](http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model) directive that covers all cases:

- simple array of primitives
- array of objects (pick id or whole object)
- object properties iteration

For topic-starter case it would be:

```html
<label ng-repeat="fruit in ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'naartjie']">
    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="selectedFruits" checklist-value="fruit"> {{fruit}}
</label>
```

Comment: That looks like what I need. Is there any chance you could explain how to use it when getting the data asynchronously?  That part is confusing to me.

Comment: After you're getting the data asynchronously just modify the checlist model in the scope, in the above example `selectedFruits`.

Answer (score 11):

Using a string of `$index` can help to use a hashmap of selected values:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="someItem in someArray">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="someObject[$index.toString()]" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

This way the ng-model object gets updated with the key representing the index.

```
$scope.someObject = {};
```

After a while `$scope.someObject` should look something like:

```
$scope.someObject = {
     0: true,
     4: false,
     1: true
};
```

This method won't work for all situations, but it is easy to implement.

Answer (score 8):

I think the easiest workaround would be to use 'select' with 'multiple' specified:

```
<select ng-model="selectedfruit" multiple ng-options="v for v in fruit"></select>
```

Otherwise, I think you'll have to process the list to construct the list
(by `$watch()`ing the model array bind with checkboxes).

Comment: He's asking for a checkbox list, and yet you are telling him about select with options. Which is completely different.

Comment: @CrazySabbath: yet you are not understanding that he suggesting an alternate solution and this answer helped 6 other people as an "alternate solution"

Answer (score 8):

Since you accepted an answer in which a list was not used, I'll assume the answer to my comment question is "No, it doesn't have to be a list".  I also had the impression that maybe you were rending the HTML server side, since "checked" is present in your sample HTML (this would not be needed if ng-model were used to model your checkboxes).

Anyway, here's what I had in mind when I asked the question, also assuming you were generating the HTML server-side:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" 
 ng-init="checkboxes = {apple: true, orange: false, pear: true, naartjie: false}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.apple">apple
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.orange">orange
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.pear">pear
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.naartjie">naartjie
    <br>{{checkboxes}}
</div>
```

ng-init allows server-side generated HTML to initially set certain checkboxes.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/CBmgM/).

Answer (score 6):

The following solution seems like a good option,

```
<label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    ng-model="fruit.checked"
    ng-value="true"
  > {{fruit.fruitName}}
</label>
```

And in controller model value `fruits` will be like this

```
$scope.fruits = [
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "checked": true
  },
  {
    "name": "orange"
  },
  {
    "name": "grapes",
    "checked": true
  }
];
```

Comment: the more I am looking at these examples it seems i will have to map my array into an array of objects.

Answer (score 5):

I have adapted Yoshi's accepted answer to deal with complex objects (instead of strings).

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <p ng-repeat="permission in allPermissions">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selectedPermissions.containsObjectWithProperty('id', permission.id)" ng-click="toggleSelection(permission)" />
        {{permission.name}}
    </p>

    <hr />

    <p>allPermissions: | <span ng-repeat="permission in allPermissions">{{permission.name}} | </span></p>
    <p>selectedPermissions: | <span ng-repeat="permission in selectedPermissions">{{permission.name}} | </span></p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
Array.prototype.indexOfObjectWithProperty = function(propertyName, propertyValue)
{
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (this[i][propertyName] === propertyValue) return i;
    }

    return -1;
};


Array.prototype.containsObjectWithProperty = function(propertyName, propertyValue)
{
    return this.indexOfObjectWithProperty(propertyName, propertyValue) != -1;
};


function TestController($scope)
{
    $scope.allPermissions = [
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "ROLE_USER" },
    { "id" : 2, "name" : "ROLE_ADMIN" },
    { "id" : 3, "name" : "ROLE_READ" },
    { "id" : 4, "name" : "ROLE_WRITE" } ];

    $scope.selectedPermissions = [
    { "id" : 1, "name" : "ROLE_USER" },
    { "id" : 3, "name" : "ROLE_READ" } ];

    $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(permission) {
        var index = $scope.selectedPermissions.indexOfObjectWithProperty('id', permission.id);

        if (index > -1) {
            $scope.selectedPermissions.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            $scope.selectedPermissions.push(permission);
        }
    };
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/tCU8v/

Comment: You should never have an `<input type="checkbox">` without a wrapping or matching `<label>`!  Now your users have to click on the actual checkbox instead of the text next to the checkbox, which is much harder and is bad usability.

Answer (score 5):

Another simple directive could be like:

```
var appModule = angular.module("appModule", []);

appModule.directive("checkList", [function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: {
        selectedItemsArray: "=",
        value: "@"
    },
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        scope.$watchCollection("selectedItemsArray", function (newValue) {
            if (_.contains(newValue, scope.value)) {
                elem.prop("checked", true);
            } else {
                elem.prop("checked", false);
            }
        });
        if (_.contains(scope.selectedItemsArray, scope.value)) {
            elem.prop("checked", true);
        }
        elem.on("change", function () {
            if (elem.prop("checked")) {
                if (!_.contains(scope.selectedItemsArray, scope.value)) {
                    scope.$apply(
                        function () {
                            scope.selectedItemsArray.push(scope.value);
                        }
                    );
                }
            } else {
                if (_.contains(scope.selectedItemsArray, scope.value)) {
                    var index = scope.selectedItemsArray.indexOf(scope.value);
                    scope.$apply(
                        function () {
                            scope.selectedItemsArray.splice(index, 1);
                        });
                }
            }
            console.log(scope.selectedItemsArray);
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

The controller:

```
appModule.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function ($scope) {
    //#region "Scope Members"
    $scope.sourceArray = [{ id: 1, text: "val1" }, { id: 2, text: "val2" }];
    $scope.selectedItems = ["1"];
    //#endregion
    $scope.selectAll = function () {
      $scope.selectedItems = ["1", "2"];
  };
    $scope.unCheckAll = function () {
      $scope.selectedItems = [];
    };
}]);
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled filter-list">
<li data-ng-repeat="item in sourceArray">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" check-list selected-items-array="selectedItems" value="{{item.id}}">
            {{item.text}}
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
```

I'm also including a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XnFtyij4ed6RyFwnFN6V?p=preview

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to write all that code.  AngularJS will keep the model and the checkboxes in sync simply by using ngTrueValue and ngFalseValue

Codepen here:  http://codepen.io/paulbhartzog/pen/kBhzn

Code snippet:

```
<p ng-repeat="item in list1" class="item" id="{{item.id}}">
  <strong>{{item.id}}</strong> <input name='obj1_data' type="checkbox" ng-model="list1[$index].data" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"> Click this to change data value below
</p>
<pre>{{list1 | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: This is not what OP’s asking for.

Comment: Binding checkboxes to a list is what was asked, and what I did.  The array can be modified to suit the application.  The point is that the checkboxes are bound. ngTrueValue and ngFalseValue can also be used to map to a second array that only lists other attributes, such as names.

Comment: OP wants a list of checked values, not a list of all values, checked and unchecked.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to work on the array directly and use ng-model at the same time through `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"`.

The trick is to use a getter/setter function in your ng-model. This way you can use an array as your real model and "fake" the booleans in the input's model:

```html
<label ng-repeat="fruitName in ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'naartjie']">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    ng-model="fruitsGetterSetterGenerator(fruitName)"
    ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"
  > {{fruitName}}
</label>
```

```
$scope.fruits = ['apple', 'pear']; // pre checked

$scope.fruitsGetterSetterGenerator = function(fruitName){
    return function myGetterSetter(nowHasFruit){
        if (nowHasFruit !== undefined){

            // Setter
            fruitIndex = $scope.fruits.indexOf(fruit);
            didHaveFruit = (fruitIndex !== -1);
            mustAdd = (!didHaveFruit && nowHasFruit);
            mustDel = (didHaveFruit && !nowHasFruit);
            if (mustAdd){
                $scope.fruits.push(fruit);
            }
            if (mustDel){
                $scope.fruits.splice(fruitIndex, 1);
            }
        }
        else {
            // Getter
            return $scope.user.fruits.indexOf(fruit) !== -1;
        }
    }
}
```

**CAVEAT** You shouldn't use this method if your arrays are big as `myGetterSetter` will be called a lot of times.

For more on that, see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions.

Answer (score 4):

Check out this directive that manages effectively lists of checkboxes. I hope it works for you.
[CheckList Model](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/)

Answer (score 3):

You can combine AngularJS and jQuery. For example, you need to define an array, `$scope.selected = [];`, in the controller.

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[$index]" ng-true-value="'{{item}}'">{{item}}
</label>
```

You can get an array owning the selected items. Using method `alert(JSON.stringify($scope.selected))`, you can check the selected items.

Comment: Perfect!... this is the simplest solution using an array not an object

Comment: Dont combine Jquery and Angular

Comment: This will lead to holes in selected Array. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38213658/4850220)

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another solution. The upside of my solution:

- It does not need any additional watches (which may have an impact on performance)
- It does not require any code in the controller keeping it clean
- The code is still somewhat short
- It is requires very little code to reuse in multiple places because it is just a directive

Here is the directive:

```javascript
function ensureArray(o) {
    var lAngular = angular;
    if (lAngular.isArray(o) || o === null || lAngular.isUndefined(o)) {
        return o;
    }
    return [o];
}

function checkboxArraySetDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var name = attrs.checkboxArraySet;

            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
                return (ensureArray(value) || []).indexOf(name) >= 0;
            });

            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
                var modelValue = ensureArray(ngModel.$modelValue) || [],
                    oldPos = modelValue.indexOf(name),
                    wasSet = oldPos >= 0;
                if (value) {
                    if (!wasSet) {
                        modelValue = angular.copy(modelValue);
                        modelValue.push(name);
                    }
                } else if (wasSet) {
                    modelValue = angular.copy(modelValue);
                    modelValue.splice(oldPos, 1);
                }
                return modelValue;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

At the end then just use it like this:

```html
<input ng-repeat="fruit in ['apple', 'banana', '...']" type="checkbox" ng-model="fruits" checkbox-array-set="{{fruit}}" />
```

And that is all there is. The only addition is the `checkbox-array-set` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I like Yoshi's answer. I enhanced it so You can use the same function for multiple lists.

```
<label ng-repeat="fruitName in fruits">
<input
type="checkbox"
name="selectedFruits[]"
value="{{fruitName}}"
ng-checked="selection.indexOf(fruitName) > -1"
ng-click="toggleSelection(fruitName, selection)"> {{fruitName}}
</label>


<label ng-repeat="veggieName in veggies">
<input
type="checkbox"
name="selectedVeggies[]"
value="{{veggieName}}"
ng-checked="veggieSelection.indexOf(veggieName) > -1"
ng-click="toggleSelection(veggieName, veggieSelection)"> {{veggieName}}
</label>



app.controller('SimpleArrayCtrl', ['$scope', function SimpleArrayCtrl($scope) {
  // fruits
  $scope.fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'naartjie'];
  $scope.veggies = ['lettuce', 'cabbage', 'tomato']
  // selected fruits
  $scope.selection = ['apple', 'pear'];
  $scope.veggieSelection = ['lettuce']
  // toggle selection for a given fruit by name
  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(selectionName, listSelection) {
    var idx = listSelection.indexOf(selectionName);

    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
      listSelection.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    // is newly selected
    else {
      listSelection.push(selectionName);
    }
  };
}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KcbtzEyNMA8s1X7Hja8p?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

In the HTML (supposing that the checkboxes are in the first column of every row in a table).

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in fruits">
    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-click="getChecked(item)"></td>
    <td ng-bind="fruit.name"></td>
    <td ng-bind="fruit.color"></td>
    ...
</tr>
```

In the `controllers.js` file:

```
// The data initialization part...
$scope.fruits = [
    {
      name: ....,
      color:....
    },
    {
      name: ....,
      color:....
    }
     ...
    ];

// The checked or not data is stored in the object array elements themselves
$scope.fruits.forEach(function(item){
    item.checked = false;
});

// The array to store checked fruit items
$scope.checkedItems = [];

// Every click on any checkbox will trigger the filter to find checked items
$scope.getChecked = function(item){
    $scope.checkedItems = $filter("filter")($scope.fruits,{checked:true});
};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple checkboxes on the same form

The controller code

```
vm.doYouHaveCheckBox = ['aaa', 'ccc', 'bbb'];
vm.desiredRoutesCheckBox = ['ddd', 'ccc', 'Default'];
vm.doYouHaveCBSelection = [];
vm.desiredRoutesCBSelection = [];
```

View code

```
<div ng-repeat="doYouHaveOption in vm.doYouHaveCheckBox">
    <div class="action-checkbox">
        <input id="{{doYouHaveOption}}" type="checkbox" value="{{doYouHaveOption}}" ng-checked="vm.doYouHaveCBSelection.indexOf(doYouHaveOption) > -1" ng-click="vm.toggleSelection(doYouHaveOption,vm.doYouHaveCBSelection)" />
        <label for="{{doYouHaveOption}}"></label>
        {{doYouHaveOption}}
    </div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="desiredRoutesOption in vm.desiredRoutesCheckBox">
     <div class="action-checkbox">
          <input id="{{desiredRoutesOption}}" type="checkbox" value="{{desiredRoutesOption}}" ng-checked="vm.desiredRoutesCBSelection.indexOf(desiredRoutesOption) > -1" ng-click="vm.toggleSelection(desiredRoutesOption,vm.desiredRoutesCBSelection)" />
          <label for="{{desiredRoutesOption}}"></label>
          {{desiredRoutesOption}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inspired from Yoshi's post above.
Here is the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eTwzbPhV11SuavRTsoAm?p=preview).

```js
(function () {
   
   angular
      .module("APP", [])
      .controller("demoCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
         var dc = this
         
         dc.list = [
            "Selection1",
            "Selection2",
            "Selection3"
         ]

         dc.multipleSelections = []
         dc.individualSelections = []
         
         // Using splice and push methods to make use of 
         // the same "selections" object passed by reference to the 
         // addOrRemove function as using "selections = []" 
         // creates a new object within the scope of the 
         // function which doesn't help in two way binding.
         dc.addOrRemove = function (selectedItems, item, isMultiple) {
            var itemIndex = selectedItems.indexOf(item)
            var isPresent = (itemIndex > -1)
            if (isMultiple) {
               if (isPresent) {
                  selectedItems.splice(itemIndex, 1)
               } else {
                  selectedItems.push(item)
               }
            } else {
               if (isPresent) {
                  selectedItems.splice(0, 1)
               } else {
                  selectedItems.splice(0, 1, item)
               }
            }
         }
         
      }])
   
})()
```

```css
label {
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
   </head>

   <body ng-app="APP" ng-controller="demoCtrl as dc">
      <h1>checkbox-select demo</h1>
      
      <h4>Multiple Selections</h4>
      <label ng-repeat="thing in dc.list">
         <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            ng-checked="dc.multipleSelections.indexOf(thing) > -1"
            ng-click="dc.addOrRemove(dc.multipleSelections, thing, true)"
         > {{thing}}
      </label>
      
      <p>
         dc.multipleSelections :- {{dc.multipleSelections}}
      </p>
      
      <hr>
      
      <h4>Individual Selections</h4>
      <label ng-repeat="thing in dc.list">
         <input 
            type="checkbox" 
            ng-checked="dc.individualSelections.indexOf(thing) > -1"
            ng-click="dc.addOrRemove(dc.individualSelections, thing, false)"
         > {{thing}}
      </label>
      
      <p>
         dc.invidualSelections :- {{dc.individualSelections}}
      </p>
      
      <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on my other post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-to-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs/14520103?noredirect=1#answer-38194899), I have made a reusable directive.

Check out the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Vikasg7/checkbox-select)

```js
(function () {
   
   angular
      .module("checkbox-select", [])
      .directive("checkboxModel", ["$compile", function ($compile) {
         return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
               // Defining updateSelection function on the parent scope
               if (!scope.$parent.updateSelections) {
                  // Using splice and push methods to make use of 
                  // the same "selections" object passed by reference to the 
                  // addOrRemove function as using "selections = []" 
                  // creates a new object within the scope of the 
                  // function which doesn't help in two way binding.
                  scope.$parent.updateSelections = function (selectedItems, item, isMultiple) {
                     var itemIndex = selectedItems.indexOf(item)
                     var isPresent = (itemIndex > -1)
                     if (isMultiple) {
                        if (isPresent) {
                           selectedItems.splice(itemIndex, 1)
                        } else {
                           selectedItems.push(item)
                        }
                     } else {
                        if (isPresent) {
                           selectedItems.splice(0, 1)
                        } else {
                           selectedItems.splice(0, 1, item)
                        }
                     }
                  }   
               }
               
               // Adding or removing attributes
               ele.attr("ng-checked", attrs.checkboxModel + ".indexOf(" + attrs.checkboxValue + ") > -1")
               var multiple = attrs.multiple ? "true" : "false"
               ele.attr("ng-click", "updateSelections(" + [attrs.checkboxModel, attrs.checkboxValue, multiple].join(",") + ")")
               
               // Removing the checkbox-model attribute, 
               // it will avoid recompiling the element infinitly
               ele.removeAttr("checkbox-model")
               ele.removeAttr("checkbox-value")
               ele.removeAttr("multiple")
               
               $compile(ele)(scope)
            }
         }
      }])
   
      // Defining app and controller
      angular
      .module("APP", ["checkbox-select"])
      .controller("demoCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
         var dc = this
         dc.list = [
            "selection1",
            "selection2",
            "selection3"
         ]
         
         // Define the selections containers here
         dc.multipleSelections = []
         dc.individualSelections = []
      }])
   
})()
```

```css
label {
  display: block;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
      
   </head>
   
   <body ng-app="APP" ng-controller="demoCtrl as dc">
      <h1>checkbox-select demo</h1>
      
      <h4>Multiple Selections</h4>
      <label ng-repeat="thing in dc.list">
         <input type="checkbox" checkbox-model="dc.multipleSelections" checkbox-value="thing" multiple>
         {{thing}}
      </label>
      <p>dc.multipleSelecitons:- {{dc.multipleSelections}}</p>
      
      <h4>Individual Selections</h4>
      <label ng-repeat="thing in dc.list">
         <input type="checkbox" checkbox-model="dc.individualSelections" checkbox-value="thing">
         {{thing}}
      </label>
      <p>dc.individualSelecitons:- {{dc.individualSelections}}</p>
      
      <script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
      <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  <div ng-app='app' >
    <div ng-controller='MainCtrl' >
       <ul> 
       <li ng-repeat="tab in data">
         <input type='checkbox' ng-click='change($index,confirm)' ng-model='confirm' />
         {{tab.name}} 
         </li>
     </ul>
    {{val}}
   </div>
 </div>


var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.val=[];
  $scope.confirm=false;
  $scope.data=[
   {
     name:'vijay'
     },
    {
      name:'krishna'
    },{
      name:'Nikhil'
     }
    ];
    $scope.temp;
   $scope.change=function(index,confirm){
     console.log(confirm);
    if(!confirm){
     ($scope.val).push($scope.data[index]);   
    }
    else{
    $scope.temp=$scope.data[index];
        var d=($scope.val).indexOf($scope.temp);
        if(d!=undefined){
         ($scope.val).splice(d,1);
        }    
       }
     }   
   })
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this: [checklist-model](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/).

It works with JavaScript arrays, and objects and it can use static HTML checkboxes, without ng-repeat

```
<label><input type="checkbox" checklist-model="roles" value="admin"> Administrator</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checklist-model="roles" value="customer"> Customer</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checklist-model="roles" value="guest"> Guest</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" checklist-model="roles" value="user"> User</label>
```

And the JavaScript side:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["checklist-model"]);
app.controller('Ctrl4a', function($scope) {
    $scope.roles = [];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple HTML only way of doing it:

```html
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-checked="fruits.indexOf('apple') > -1"
       ng-click="fruits.indexOf('apple') > -1 ? fruits.splice(fruits.indexOf('apple'), 1) : fruits.push('apple')">
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-checked="fruits.indexOf('orange') > -1"
       ng-click="fruits.indexOf('orange') > -1 ? fruits.splice(fruits.indexOf('orange'), 1) : fruits.push('orange')">
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-checked="fruits.indexOf('pear') > -1"
       ng-click="fruits.indexOf('pear') > -1 ? fruits.splice(fruits.indexOf('pear'), 1) : fruits.push('pear')">
<input type="checkbox"
       ng-checked="fruits.indexOf('naartjie') > -1"
       ng-click="fruits.indexOf('apple') > -1 ? fruits.splice(fruits.indexOf('apple'), 1) : fruits.push('naartjie')">
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516885/3332734) of the @Umur Kontacı, I think in using to catch selected data throughout another object/array, like a edit page.

#### Catch options at the database

[image]

#### Toggle a some option

[image]

As example, all colors json in below:

```
{
    "colors": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Preto - #000000"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Azul - #005AB1"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Azul Marinho - #001A66"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Amarelo - #FFF100"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title": "Vermelho - #E92717"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title": "Verde - #008D2F"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "title": "Cinza - #8A8A8A"
        },
        {
            "id": 8,
            "title": "Prata - #C8C9CF"
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "title": "Rosa - #EF586B"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "title": "Nude - #E4CAA6"
        },
        {
            "id": 11,
            "title": "Laranja - #F68700"
        },
        {
            "id": 12,
            "title": "Branco - #FFFFFF"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "title": "Marrom - #764715"
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "title": "Dourado - #D9A300"
        },
        {
            "id": 15,
            "title": "Bordo - #57001B"
        },
        {
            "id": 16,
            "title": "Roxo - #3A0858"
        },
        {
            "id": 18,
            "title": "Estampado "
        },
        {
            "id": 17,
            "title": "Bege - #E5CC9D"
        }
    ]
}
```

And 2 types of data object, `array` with one object and `object` containing two/more object data:

- Two items selected catched at the database:

  ```
  [{"id":12,"title":"Branco - #FFFFFF"},{"id":16,"title":"Roxo - #3A0858"}]
  ```
- One item selected catched at the database:

  ```
  {"id":12,"title":"Branco - #FFFFFF"}
  ```

And here, my javascript code:

```
/**
 * Add this code after catch data of database.
 */

vm.checkedColors = [];
var _colorObj = vm.formData.color_ids;
var _color_ids = [];

if (angular.isObject(_colorObj)) {
    // vm.checkedColors.push(_colorObj);
    _color_ids.push(_colorObj);
} else if (angular.isArray(_colorObj)) {
    angular.forEach(_colorObj, function (value, key) {
        // vm.checkedColors.push(key + ':' + value);
        _color_ids.push(key + ':' + value);
    });
}

angular.forEach(vm.productColors, function (object) {
    angular.forEach(_color_ids, function (color) {
        if (color.id === object.id) {
            vm.checkedColors.push(object);
        }
    });
});

/**
 * Add this code in your js function initialized in this HTML page
 */
vm.toggleColor = function (color) {
    console.log('toggleColor is: ', color);

    if (vm.checkedColors.indexOf(color) === -1) {
        vm.checkedColors.push(color);
    } else {
        vm.checkedColors.splice(vm.checkedColors.indexOf(color), 1);
    }
    vm.formData.color_ids = vm.checkedColors;
};
```

My Html code:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="color in productColors">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
               ng-checked="checkedColors.indexOf(color) != -1"
               ng-click="toggleColor(color)"/>
        <% color.title %>
    </label>
</div>

<p>checkedColors Output:</p>
<pre><% checkedColors %></pre>
```

## [Edit] Refactored code below:

```
function makeCheckedOptions(objectOptions, optionObj) {
    var checkedOptions = [];
    var savedOptions = [];

    if (angular.isObject(optionObj)) {
        savedOptions.push(optionObj);
    } else if (angular.isArray(optionObj)) {
        angular.forEach(optionObj, function (value, key) {
            savedOptions.push(key + ':' + value);
        });
    }

    angular.forEach(objectOptions, function (object) {
        angular.forEach(savedOptions, function (color) {
            if (color.id === object.id) {
                checkedOptions.push(object);
            }
        });
    });

    return checkedOptions;
}
```

And call new method as below:

```
vm.checkedColors = makeCheckedOptions(productColors, vm.formData.color_ids);
```

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

I've put an array in the controller.

```
$scope.statuses = [{ name: 'Shutdown - Reassessment Required' },
    { name: 'Under Construction' },
    { name: 'Administrative Cancellation' },
    { name: 'Initial' },
    { name: 'Shutdown - Temporary' },
    { name: 'Decommissioned' },
    { name: 'Active' },
    { name: 'SO Shutdown' }]
```

On the markup I've put something like following

```
<div ng-repeat="status in $scope.statuses">
   <input type="checkbox" name="unit_status" ng-model="$scope.checkboxes[status.name]"> {{status.name}}
   <br>                        
</div>
{{$scope.checkboxes}}
```

The output was the following, in the controller I just needed to check whether its true or false; true for checked, absent/false for unchecked.

```
{
"Administrative Cancellation":true,
"Under Construction":true,
"Shutdown - Reassessment Required":true,
"Decommissioned":true,
"Active":true
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following way is more clear and useful for nested ng-repeats. Check it out on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oMCKACELU5EMwoWrzuOd?p=preview).

[Quote from this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614361/how-to-update-ng-model-dynamically-in-ng-repeat/17614803#17614803):

```
<html ng-app="plunker">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="tab in mytabs">

            <h1>{{tab.name}}</h1>
            <div ng-repeat="val in tab.values">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-change="checkValues()" ng-model="val.checked"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <pre> {{selected}} </pre>

            <script>
                var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

                app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope,$filter) {
                    $scope.mytabs = [
             {
                 name: "tab1",
                 values: [
                     { value: "value1",checked:false },
                     { value: "value2", checked: false },
                     { value: "value3", checked: false },
                     { value: "value4", checked: false }
                 ]
             },
             {
                 name: "tab2",
                 values: [
                     { value: "value1", checked: false },
                     { value: "value2", checked: false },
                     { value: "value3", checked: false },
                     { value: "value4", checked: false }
                 ]
             }
                    ]
                    $scope.selected = []
                    $scope.checkValues = function () {
                        angular.forEach($scope.mytabs, function (value, index) {
                         var selectedItems = $filter('filter')(value.values, { checked: true });
                         angular.forEach(selectedItems, function (value, index) {
                             $scope.selected.push(value);
                         });

                        });
                    console.log($scope.selected);
                    };
                });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the jsFillde link for the same, http://jsfiddle.net/techno2mahi/Lfw96ja6/.

This uses the directive which is available for download at http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/.

This is the good to have directive as your application will need this functionality much often.

The code is below:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="ng-scope" ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl1">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <h3>Multi Checkbox List Demo</h3>
            <div class="well">  <!-- ngRepeat: role in roles -->
                <label ng-repeat="role in roles">
                    <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role"> {{role}}
                </label>
            </div>

            <br>
            <button ng-click="checkAll()">check all</button>
            <button ng-click="uncheckAll()">uncheck all</button>
            <button ng-click="checkFirst()">check first</button>
            <div>
                <h3>Selected User Roles </h3>
                <pre class="ng-binding">{{user.roles|json}}</pre>
            </div>

            <br>
            <div><b/>Provided by techno2Mahi</b></div>
        </div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["checklist-model"]);
app.controller('Ctrl1', function($scope) {
  $scope.roles = [
    'guest',
    'user',
    'customer',
    'admin'
  ];
  $scope.user = {
    roles: ['user']
  };
  $scope.checkAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = angular.copy($scope.roles);
  };
  $scope.uncheckAll = function() {
    $scope.user.roles = [];
  };
  $scope.checkFirst = function() {
    $scope.user.roles.splice(0, $scope.user.roles.length);
    $scope.user.roles.push('guest');
  };
});
```

Comment: The HTML is not well-formed - there are more opening tags `<div>` than closing, `</div>`. Have you left something out?

Answer (score 0):

Try my baby:

**

```
myApp.filter('inputSelected', function(){
  return function(formData){
    var keyArr = [];
    var word = [];
    Object.keys(formData).forEach(function(key){
    if (formData[key]){
        var keyCap = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
      for (var char = 0; char<keyCap.length; char++ ) {
        if (keyCap[char] == keyCap[char].toUpperCase()){
          var spacedLetter = ' '+ keyCap[char];
          word.push(spacedLetter);
        }
        else {
          word.push(keyCap[char]);
        }
      }
    }
    keyArr.push(word.join(''))
    word = [];
    })
    return keyArr.toString();
  }
})
```

**

Then for any ng-model with checkboxes, it will return a string of all the input you selected:

```
<label for="Heard about ITN">How did you hear about ITN?: *</label><br>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input ng-model="formData.heardAboutItn.brotherOrSister" type="checkbox" >Brother or Sister</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input ng-model="formData.heardAboutItn.friendOrAcquaintance" type="checkbox" >Friend or Acquaintance</label>


{{formData.heardAboutItn | inputSelected }}

//returns Brother or Sister, Friend or Acquaintance
```