# ng-click stops check box from being checked

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of check boxes...

```
<div class="checkBoxGroup" ng-repeat="service in getAdditionalServices()">
                <input ng-click="additionalServiceClick($index)" type="checkbox" value="{{service.text}}"><span class="fieldTitle">{{service.text}}</span>
</div>
```

Event handler...

```
$scope.additionalServiceClick = function ($index) {


};
```

In the 'additionalServiceClick' function I want to update an array of checked services. But angular unselects any attempt to check a check box if an ng-click handler is assigned.

How to get Angular to bog off in this instance?

Comment: I've had instances where a click event triggered the view to refresh, but the model was never updated with the new values, so it appeared that it was unchecking by boxes. I can't remember the solution, but it's something you can look into.

Comment: Yes I was just thinking that was the problem. I've hard coded the list of check boxes for now.

Comment: This guy's got the right idea.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14520103/221683

Comment: When returning my services for binding I've wrapped them in another object that contains an additional property of whether the item has been selected which is derived from looking for the item in the array of selected services.

Comment: Horribly slow though.