# Saving a checkbox list in Angularjs with node

Tags: angularjs

I want to save and load a checkbox list using binding in angularjs with a node backend. This SO question ([How do I bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values)) answers how I can load the check box from a static javascript object but how can I save the checkbox values after the user selects them?

I want to save the checkbox values in a single field but how can I tell angular to bind the checkbox values into a single field defined in a model to my mongodb? I cant just use ng-model as there are multiple checkboxes.

Needless to say that I am new to angular so any help here is greatly appreciated ...

Thanks for any help you can provide.

kseudo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `ng-model` to your checkbox. By this way you can update model in controller on any checkbox state change.

Here is example:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <label ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    name="fruit.name"
   ng-model="fruit.value"
  > {{fruit.name}}
</label>
    <pre>{{fruits| json}}</pre>    
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.fruits = [{
        name: 'apple',
        value: false
    }, {
        name: 'orange',
        value: false
    }, {
        name: 'pear',
        value: false
    }, {
        name: 'naartjie',
        value: false
    }];
}
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/183/)**</kbd>

**[EDIT]**

BTW we can make the copy by using `angular.copy()` method. When we press button, the new copy of `fruits` model will be created (and you should send it to server as json). Old model `fruits` will stay the same:

```
$scope.fruitsCopy = [];

 $scope.init = function(){
  $scope.fruitsCopy = angular.copy($scope.fruits );
}
```

To convert data to JSon I would use:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify($scope.fruitsCopy);
```

Demo2 <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PQvQ2/183/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Maxim. I want to save the checkbox values as a json string in a field of a model.

So when the user clicks save, this string is generated:
[
    { name: 'apple',    checked: true },
    { name: 'orange',   checked: false }
]
and saved to a model like team.fruits.

Could you suggest some code on how I can use the state change to achieve this?

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again for your super quick reply Maxim. How can I pass the value evaluated by {{fruits| json}} to the controller so that it will be saved to a model field eg"foods.fruits"? At the moment I just cant see how this value can be passed through to the controller....

Comment: controller has `$scope.fruits` - this is your model and this model changes if you lpay with GUI (in basic words)

Comment: Its take me about four hours but I finally have a checkbox that save and populates correctly. Many thanks Maxim for taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: One last thing: why do I have to make a copy of the fruits model? I think this must have something to do with scope but Im struggling to understand this...

Comment: You can remove it. Its just example how to do copy of model. When you press on send button you send your model to server.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you defined your model as such:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
      name: 'A',
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 'B',
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 'C',
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 'D',
      checked: false
    }];
}
```

And created a view for the model:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked">
        {{item.name}}
      </label>
   </li>
</ul>
<button ng-click="save()">save</button>
```

Next you have to define `save` function:

```
$scope.save = function() {
  //angular.toJson converts array to string, something like
  // '[{"name":"A","checked":false},{"name":"B","checked":true},...]'
  var json = angular.toJson($scope.items);
  //Service is angular service for your model that makes http requests to your backend
  Service.save(json).then(function(){
    //here you can notify user that data is persisted
  }, function() {
    //here you can notify user that there was a problem with request
  });
}
```

And a simple model service:

```
.service('Service', function($http) {
   return new function() {
     this.save = function(data) {
       return $http.post('url/to/backend', data);
     }
   }
 });
```