# Cant get Select Box to update dynamically with angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently learning angularJS and so far so good, but I'm having a problem that I cant seem to figure out.

I have 2 select boxes, one with top level categories in it, and a second one for sub-categories which is supposed to dynamically update when a change is made to the first select.

The first select box is populating fine, but despite the values being set for the second binding array by the event function I developed, the view never updates the second select box with the new values. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and have tried a bunch of things but with no luck.

Here is what I've got:

```
var themebucketApp = angular.module('themebucketApp',[]);

//category list controller
themebucketApp.controller('CategoriesOptions',function($scope) {

    $scope.thememap = {"wordpress":[{"category":"Activism"},{"category":"Art"},{"category":"Blog \/ Magazine"},{"category":"BuddyPress"},{"category":"Business"},{"category":"Cart66"},{"category":"Charity"},{"category":"Children"},{"category":"Churches"},{"category":"Computer"},{"category":"Corporate"},{"category":"Creative"},{"category":"eCommerce"},{"category":"Entertainment"},{"category":"Environmental"},{"category":"Events"},{"category":"Experimental"},{"category":"Fashion"},{"category":"Film & TV"},{"category":"Food"},{"category":"Government"},{"category":"Health & Beauty"},{"category":"Hosting"},{"category":"Jigoshop"},{"category":"Marketing"},{"category":"Miscellaneous"},{"category":"Mobile"},{"category":"Music and Bands"},{"category":"News \/ Editorial"},{"category":"Nightlife"},{"category":"Nonprofit"},{"category":"Personal"},{"category":"Photography"},{"category":"Political"},{"category":"Portfolio"},{"category":"Restaurants & Cafes"},{"category":"Retail"},{"category":"Shopping"},{"category":"Software"},{"category":"Technology"},{"category":"Travel"},{"category":"Wedding"},{"category":"WooCommerce"},{"category":"WordPress"},{"category":"WP e-Commerce"}],"magento":[{"category":"Entertainment"},{"category":"Fashion"},{"category":"Health & Beauty"},{"category":"Magento"},{"category":"Miscellaneous"},{"category":"Shopping"},{"category":"Technology"}],"designs":[{"category":"404 Pages"},{"category":"Activism"},{"category":"Admin Templates"},{"category":"Art"},{"category":"Business"},{"category":"Charity"},{"category":"Children"},{"category":"Churches"},{"category":"Computer"},{"category":"Corporate"},{"category":"Creative"},{"category":"Electronics"},{"category":"Entertainment"},{"category":"Environmental"},{"category":"Events"},{"category":"Experimental"},{"category":"Fashion"},{"category":"Film & TV"},{"category":"Food"},{"category":"Government"},{"category":"Health & Beauty"},{"category":"Hosting"},{"category":"Marketing"},{"category":"Miscellaneous"},{"category":"Mobile"},{"category":"Music and Bands"},{"category":"Nightlife"},{"category":"Nonprofit"},{"category":"Personal"},{"category":"Photo Gallery"},{"category":"Photography"},{"category":"Political"},{"category":"Portfolio"},{"category":"Restaurants & Cafes"},{"category":"Resume \/ CV"},{"category":"Retail"},{"category":"Shopping"},{"category":"Site Templates"},{"category":"Social Media Home"},{"category":"Software"},{"category":"Specialty Pages"},{"category":"Technology"},{"category":"Travel"},{"category":"Under Construction"},{"category":"Virtual Business Card"},{"category":"Wedding"}],"opencart":[{"category":"Entertainment"},{"category":"Fashion"},{"category":"Miscellaneous"},{"category":"OpenCart"},{"category":"Shopping"},{"category":"Technology"}]};

    $scope.categories  = [{'name' : 'WordPress', 'value' : 'wordpress'},{'name' : 'Magento', 'value' : 'magento'},{'name' : 'OpenCart', 'value' : 'opencart'},{'name' : 'Designs', 'value' : 'designs'}];

    $scope.subcategories = [];

    $scope.loadSubcategories = function(){
        $scope.subcategories = $scope.thememap[$('#theme-type').val()];
    };

});
```

...

```
<div class="navbar-text pull-right" style="margin-top:10px;">
    <select id="theme-type" name="themetype" ng-controller="CategoriesOptions" ng-click="loadSubcategories();">
        <option value="">Theme Type</option>
        <option ng-repeat='category in categories' value="{{category.value}}">{{category.name}}</option>
    </select>
    <select id="theme-cat" name="themecat" ng-controller='CategoriesOptions'>
        <option value="All">All</option>
        <option ng-repeat='subcategory in subcategories' value='{{subcategory.category}}'>{{subcategory.category}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: Why not use `ng-options` here?

Comment: You may want to have a look at a question I posed a while back. Sounds like a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20845713/2644281 The accepted answer worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues:

**One**:  `ng-controller="CategoriesOptions"` should be declared only once and not one per control Like this:

```
<div class="navbar-text pull-right" style="margin-top:10px;" ng-controller="CategoriesOptions">
<select id="theme-type" name="themetype" ng-click="loadSubcategories();">
    <option value="">Theme Type</option>
    <option ng-repeat='category in categories' value="{{category.value}}">{{category.name}}</option>
</select>
<select id="theme-cat" name="themecat" >
    <option value="All">All</option>
    <option ng-repeat='subcategory in subcategories' value='{{subcategory.category}}'>{{subcategory.category}}</option>
</select>
```

**Two** for selects it better to use `ng-options` and `ng-model`:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

About:

```
ng-model="{string}"
```

It is what associates the selected value of the control with your model.

About:

```
 [ng-options="{comprehension_expression}"]
```

it works something like this:

```
<select ng-model="mySelectedValue" ng-options="c.name for c in categories"></select>
```