# How to pre-populate and bind list of checkbox using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, checkbox, binding

I have a list of books and each book has id, name, and list of retailers.  What I would like to do is to load up a page where I can use checkboxes to select/unselect retailers.  When the book edit page is first loaded, the full list of retailers (each with a checkbox) are shown and then those that are the existing retailers for the book are checked.

```
app.js
allRetailers = $resource('/api/retailers');
currentRetailers = $resource('/api/books/:bookId/retailers')

partial.html
<span ng-repeat="retailer in allRetailers">
    <input type='checkbox' value='{{retailer .id}}' ng-model="book.isExistingRetailer(retailer)" >{{retailer .name}}<br/>
</span>
```

Getting the full list of retailers and saving only the checked ones is not the problem.  The problem I am having is pre-populate the checkboxes that are existing/current retailers.

I have looked at [How do I bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values) but it's not quite what I need.  Thanks in advance to your replies.

Comment: Can you provide JSfiddle/Plunker for more understanding?

Comment: @ArtyomPranovich, sorry I gave up half way trying to post it on JSfiddle.  But I was able to get it working now.  Problem was that I was not using callback and thus the existing retailers list was always empty.  Thanks for your help nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `ng-checked` directive like

```
<input type='checkbox' value='{{retailer.id}}' ng-checked="book.isExistingRetailer(retailer)" ng-model="selected" ng-click="selectRetailer(book, retailer,selected)>{{retailer .name}}<br/>
```

This would mean that you need to manually select the items on checked by implementing the method `selectRetailer` defined on ng-click passing in values for book and retailer and the current selected value(true or false).

Comment: Thanks, I now use the ng-checked and I also added callback for the existing retailer list (which was always empty).  Works great now.