# AngularJS list of toggle buttons directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I wanted to create a reusable component of toggles/switches list.

I've already made a `<toggle>` directive, and now want a `<toggle-list>` containing multiple `<toggle>`'s.

```
<toggle-list>
  <toggle value="A">Toggle A</toggle>
  <toggle value="B">Toggle B</toggle>
</toggle-list>
```

.

```
app.directive("toggle", function(){
return {
    scope: {},
    restrict: "E",
    transclude:true,
    templateUrl: "toggle-element.html", 
    link: function(scope){
      scope.toggled = false;

      scope.toggle = function(){
        scope.toggled = !scope.toggled;
      }
    }
}
});
```

Here's my [working plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/jw0dpxZRFtkyqA1nwMuO?p=preview)

I want my `<toggle-list>` to return eg. array of values that are selected.
How do I implement this?
Is it even a good way of doing this, or am I just trying to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: What should `<toggle-list>` render in the above example, if button A is clicked?

Comment: Similar questions have been regularly asked and I believe it to be a feature request for some time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values

Answer (score 0):

in your child directive

```
require: '^toggleList',
```

now you have access to togglelist via the fourth parameter of the link function.

```
function(scope, el, attrs, toggleListCtrl, $transclude)
```

then you could call a method on the parent controller

from the toggle directive fill an array with the child elements  :

```
scope.rank = toggleListCtrl.addToggle(el);
```

in the parent controller:

```
this.toggles = [];
this.addToggle = function (toggle) {
  var rank = this.toggles.push(toggle);
  return rank;
};
```