# Angularjs modal acting weird with checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rac8w9g8L0eX8mlXKuVn?p=preview).

When we click on the button, it opens a modal dialog with a list of items. 2 of these items are pre-checked based on the condition in the checkbox table input.

This is the function that pushes and splices:

```
$scope.toggleCheck = function (course) {
    //debugger
    var x = $scope.checkplanneddetails(course);
    if ($scope.selectedCourses.indexOf(course) === -1){
        $scope.selectedCourses.push(course);
        $scope.planned += 3;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedCourses.splice($scope.selectedCourses.indexOf(course), 1);
        $scope.planned -= 3;
    }

    $scope.getPercentage();
};
```

When a course is selected(checked) from this list, it adds 3 to the `$scope.planned` and also increases the progress bar accordingly. Similarly it also reduces in the same way when a checkbox is unchecked.

But this functionality happens in reverse for the items that are **already checked** when the modal dialog loads. Where is the code going wrong?

Comment: $scope.selectedCourses is empty the first time a checkbox is clicked, even though some are pre-selected.

Comment: How do i get around it?

Comment: mpttid.subcategory is undefined in your plunkr, so the forEach that populates selectedCourses doesn't get filled.

Comment: can you help me in the plunker? I also have that uncheck issue

Comment: are the courses in the requirements.json supposed to be checked in the modal?  i don't think your plunker has all the data necessary to help you.

Comment: Yes they should be checked..the data that matches in both the jsons will be checked and come as checked..once the data is pushed, they will update the json again accordingly

Comment: As others told, `$scope.selectedCourses` is not populated when data is loaded. Sometimes you use `checkplanneddetails` to determine the state od the checkbox and sometimes you use `selectedCourses`. It's messy and error-prone. You should have 1 source of truth.

Comment: so which would be a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is you're trying to hold state of checkboxes in attitional array. Instead you should only use "ng-" directives (like ng-model, or ng-checked for checkboxes)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nm9N2zdBZL7IubMCatjz?p=preview

here is my modification:

```
        $scope.toggleCheck = function (course) {
            //debugger
                if(course.checked){
                    $scope.planned += 3;
                } else {
                    $scope.planned -= 3;
                }


                $scope.getPercentage();
        };
```

and also i've changed "ng-clicked" for "ng-changed", because the first one is triggered before actual change of value