# Can you get this ng-model value from ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several checkboxes in angular.js and I am trying to get the ng-model value from the selected checkbox when clicked. Any suggestions?

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="hyp" value="false" ng-click="selection($event)">
                    Hypertension
    </label>
</div>


$scope.selection = function($event){

    console.log($event.target.value);
}
```

I hope that this is clear enough :/

Comment: Have you searched before asking? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values 
I like to use the checklist-model directive

Comment: I always search before asking, thanks for the link i'll have a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can directly put your model inside your function : `ng-click="selection(hyp)"`

Comment: It isn't even necessary to pass the value if both lives on the same scope

Comment: @Sprottenwels Yes is necessary if he use the same function for all checkbox

Comment: Touché. This one goes to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value directly from the model. So you can do this:

```
$scope.hyp = false;  // You can remove the value attribute
$scope.selection = function() {
  console.log($scope.hyp);
};
```

Comment: Thanks but i'm trying to get the value of the selected checkbox by using a this. which im thinking would mean that I dont need to create a model in my js file for every checkbox?