# AngularJS checkbox ng-model as an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

My HTML is

```html
    <label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Communities" ng-model="formData.User.Communities" value="1" id="YOURROLE_0">
  COACH</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Communities" ng-model="formData.User.Communities" value="2" id="YOURROLE_1">
  ATHLETE</label>
<br>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="Communities" ng-model="formData.User.Communities" value="3" id="YOURROLE_2">
  PARENT</label>
```

How can I specify the HTML/Javascript that I get the model as below. I need the checkboxes (checked ones) as an array populated to the array.

```
.controller('formController', function($scope) {

        $scope.formData = {
            "User": {
                "Communities": [1, 2, 3]
            }
        };

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checklist Model is the answer

http://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach without a third-party library, similar to [AngularJS: How to bind selected checkbox items to empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028638/angularjs-how-to-bind-selected-checkbox-items-to-empty-array/77122477#77122477):

```js
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
  .controller("formController", function($scope) {
    $scope.communities = [
      {
        name: "COACH",
        value: 1,
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        name: "ATHLETE",
        value: 2,
        checked: false,
      },
      {
        name: "PARENT",
        value: 3,
        checked: false,
      },
    ];

    $scope.formData = {
      User: {
        Communities: []
      }
    };

    $scope.updateSelected = () => {
      $scope.formData.User.Communities = $scope.communities
        .filter(e => e.checked)
        .map(e => e.value);
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="formController">
    <div ng-repeat="community in communities">
      <label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          ng-model="community.checked"
          ng-change="updateSelected()"
          id="YOURROLE_{{$index}}"
        >
        {{community.name}}
      </label>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="selected in formData.User.Communities">
      {{selected}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See also: [How do I bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-do-i-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs)