# AngularJS: How to bind selected checkbox items to empty array

Tags: angularjs

I have the written that displays "selectable" images using checkboxes. I am trying to bind the selected images (encounter.secureImageUri) to an empty array in my controller using the following code. For some reason though it is not working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-repeat="encounter in encounters.encounters" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
     <img class="imgGallerySmall" alt="No capture taken"ng-src="{{encounter.secureImageUri}}" />
     <div>
          <p> 
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedImages" ng-change="updateSelection(encounter.secureImageUri)"/>
          </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.selectedImages = [];

$scope.updateSelection = function (item) {
        $scope.selectedImages.push(item);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a full example to debug, but if you use `ng-model` here, it should point to a single variable rather than an array:

```js
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
  .controller("imageSelectorCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.encounters = {
      encounters: [
        {
          secureImageUri: "https://picsum.photos/50/50",
          checked: false,
        },
        {
          secureImageUri: "https://picsum.photos/50/51",
          checked: false,
        },
      ]
    };

    $scope.selected = [];
    $scope.updateSelected = () => {
      $scope.selected = $scope
        .encounters
        .encounters
        .filter(e => e.checked);
    }
  });
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="exampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="imageSelectorCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="encounter in encounters.encounters" style="display: flex;">
        <img alt="No capture taken" ng-src="{{encounter.secureImageUri}}" />
        <div>
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="encounter.checked" ng-change="updateSelected()" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="img in selected">
        {{img.secureImageUri}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Or without `ng-model`, managing the array yourself based on clicks:

```js
angular.module("exampleApp", [])
  .controller("imageSelectorCtrl", function($scope) {
    const ctrl = this;
    $scope.encounters = {
      encounters: [
        {secureImageUri: "https://picsum.photos/50/50"},
        {secureImageUri: "https://picsum.photos/50/51"},
      ]
    };
    $scope.selectedImages = [];

    $scope.updateSelection = function($event, item) {
      if ($event.target.checked && !$scope.selectedImages.includes(item)) {
        $scope.selectedImages.push(item);
      }
      else if (!$event.target.checked) {
        const i = $scope.selectedImages.indexOf(item);

        if (i >= 0) {
          $scope.selectedImages.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="color-scheme" content="dark light" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.2/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="exampleApp">
    <div ng-controller="imageSelectorCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="encounter in encounters.encounters" style="display: flex;">
        <img alt="No capture taken" ng-src="{{encounter.secureImageUri}}" />
        <div>
          <p>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="updateSelection($event, encounter.secureImageUri)" />
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-repeat="img in selectedImages">
        {{img}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

See also: [How do I bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-do-i-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs)