# How do I submit a form when input ng-change in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, forms, submit

What is the "AngularJS way" of doing a form submit when any of its inputs have been clicked (or changed)?

```
<form ng-submit="submit($event)" id="myForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" ng-click="???"/>
</form>
```

I'm tempted to use jQuery and simply doing `ng-click="$('#myForm').submit()"`, but it's probably worth learning it properly.

I have tried doing `ng-click="submit($event)"`, but the error here is the `$event` object within the scope of the `input` instead of the entire `form` (correct me if I'm wrong, this is what I'm getting from the documentation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can do something like this for sure by triggering the AngularJS submit event:

```
$scope.change = function($event) {
    $timeout(function() {
        angular.element($event.target.form).triggerHandler('submit');
    });
};
```

where

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="bar" ng-click="change($event)" />
```

However I think it's better to simply use the same function in `ngClick` as used in `ngSubmit`.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/tJIYD9ZVjYzwA2aXJobo?p=preview

Comment: Trying this now, quick question: I'm trying to log the query string for the form (i.e. `?foo=bar`) in my `$scope.submit` function. In jQuery I would use `$(event.currentTarget).serialize();`. How would I console.log the query string using plain angular/jQLite?

Comment: Why do you need it? If you plan to send data with AJAX call then $http service will serialize data for you from the object. If you use jQuery you can still use `$.param({...})`.

Comment: Make sure you use ngModel directive on your input elements, like `<input type="checkbox" name="foo" ng-model="model.check" value="bar" ng-click="change($event)" /> <input type="text" ng-model="model.name">`, etc. Then you will be able to access model data as `$scope.model` - will give you an object of data, which you can send to backend using `$http`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a say in how I implement the ajax requests, I *must* obtain the query string.

Comment: Okay, if you need query string you should anyway give form elements `ngModel` directive like `ng-model="model.username"`, etc. Then in controller in submit function use `$scope.model` object to construct query string using simple for loop `for (var key in $scope.model) { ... }`. Using jQuery it would be just `$.param($scope.model)`.

Comment: The issue I have with that approach is handling checkboxes. The old fashion non-ajax way is simple: give checkboxes `name="colors[]"` and be done with it. I'm having trouble handling arrays in my query string using the `ngModel`.

Comment: Yes, in angular it's a little less convenient. There are different approaches. Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values

Answer (score 1):

ng-change is what worked for me using a text input:

```
<form>
    <select data-ng-model="headerName" data-ng-options="header for header in headers"
            data-ng-change="calculateCorrelations()"></select>
</form>
```