# Binding Angular Material Design Checkboxes to an Array in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I have a group of material design checkboxes and I would like to bind their values to an array in my controller.

To accomplish this I used the first method described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14520103/3034030).  While the values are properly being added and removed from the list, the boxes no longer display as "checked" when I click on them.  My code is below and I also recreated the problem in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/dsal1951/pen/emaNQP).

**HTML for my checkbox**

```
<md-checkbox 
    ng-repeat="site in websites" 
    value="{{site}}" 
    ng-checked="selection.indexOf(site) > -1" 
    ng-click="toggleSelection(site)"> 
    {{site}}
</md-checkbox>
```

**JavaScript from Controller**

```
  $scope.websites = ['Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Amazon'];
  $scope.selection = ['Facebook'];
  $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(site) {
    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(site);

    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }

    // is newly selected
    else {
      $scope.selection.push(site);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Since the v 0.9 release of Angular Material it looks like the code above now works, while @jarz code works for v0.8 and below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
ng-checked="selection.indexOf(site) > -1"
```

to this:

```
ng-checked="{{selection.indexOf(site) > -1}}"
```

Worked for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbNOmE

Comment: Just an update of @jarz answer, as his example do not work anymore: http://codepen.io/bora-89/pen/GNXvWJ