# How get array of checkboxes in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have some checkboxes in HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="type[]" value="5">
```

How I can get all selected values in Angular JS?

I tried to add for earch input: `ng-model="type[]"`

Comment: How do you generate the checkboxes?

Comment: It has been already answered to this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values

Comment: Checkboxes are genetated in JS/Jquery - plugin bootstrap-checkboxes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCheckbox" 
 ng-init="checkboxes = {1: true, 2: false, 3: true, 4: false}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.1">1
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.2">2
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.3">3
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes.4">4
    <br>{{checkboxes}}
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CBmgM/57/)**

Comment: How to do name for chekboxes? That in server I have: `type[] = 1, type[] = 2`

Comment: Why do you need the names for? And what you "have on server" is quite confusing.

Comment: How I will to prepare data in server if these have not name, for example `$_POST['type'][]`?