# Get Selected check box items from a click of a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I go about getting **checked** check box item's **ID** in a repeated list from a click of a button and add items to a variable / Array for later use?

html:

```
<input id="btnCheck" type="button" value="Next" ng-click="addSelected()" />    
<div ng-controller="movieController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="movie in Movies">
                    <input id="chkBox-{{ movie.MovieID }}"
                         type="checkbox"
                         ng-checked="selection.indexOf(movie.MovieID) > -1"
                         ng-click="toggleSelection(movie.MovieID)"
                    />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
$scope.AddSelected = function () {
    var selected = $scope.selection
    console.log(selected);
}

$scope.selection = [];
$scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(movie) {
    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(movie);
    if (idx > -1) {
        $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else {
        $scope.selection.push(movie);
    }
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can AngularJS bind to list of checkbox values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values)

Comment: Actually the answer in that post helped me, but not entirely. After the selection has been made, how do I access the $scope.selection values with a click of a button, say console.log it and view the objects or save it in a session variable. Maybe my approach to all this is all wrong. Bare with me guys I'm still really fresh to angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom filter which would return a selected value id, for that you need pass two parameters to filter 1st parameter will perform check, if it is true then 2nd parameter property array will be return from the filter.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="movieController">
    {{(Movies | returnPropertyWhenCheckedTrue: 'checked' :'MovieID')}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="m in Movies">
        <input id="chkBox-{{ m.MovieID }}" type="checkbox" ng-model="m.checked"/>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('returnPropertyWhenCheckedTrue', function() {
  return function(array, propertyToChecked, property) {
    var returnArray = [];
    angular.forEach(array, function(value, index) {
      if (value[propertyToChecked])
        returnArray.push(value[property]);
    });
    return returnArray;
  }
});
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r56saP5TzKRccSDj4Xqt?p=preview)

Comment: Isn't all checkboxes will have same model? Also all movies need to be in an array, since you can check multiple movies.

Comment: @jcubic I'm creating inside a `ng-repeat` that will be created inside child scope.so that would be unique in anyway.more proper way would be do `m.checked`

Comment: I find "ng-change="checked && $parent.selectedMovie = m.MovieID"" a little vague do you mind explaining?

Comment: @redM update `selectedMovie` only when check box is `checked`, if checkbox is not checked then condition will get false & `$parent.selectedMovie` will not update

Comment: Sorry I'm a little slow with this, I don't  think this is what I'm after. I'll make an edit to the question.

Comment: Sorry I can't  requires 15 rep.

Comment: @redM oh sorry I forgot

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-options for multiple select. More usefull;

```
<select name="movies" ng-model="selectedMovieIDs" 
ng-options="m.MovieID as m.MovieID for m in movies">

</select>
```

More more info : [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)