# How to get the selected check box value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to alert check box value one by one. I have 5 checkbox in the list. I want to get value of selected check box.

**View**

```
<ul class="ul-list-10">
     <li ng-repeat="assetType in assetTypeList">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="assetType.checked" ng-click="fnChangeAssetType(assetType)" value="{{assetType.Id}}" />
     </li>
 </ul>
```

**JS**

```
angular.forEach($scope.assetTypeList, function (item) {
                      //put your code here
 });
```

Comment: you can not use `ng-model` inside `ng-repeat` in this case. Its bind `assetType.checked` for all checkbox, if you checked any checkBox you get all selected.

Comment: Provide `assetTypeList`, so its help to find solution.

Comment: Please check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-can-angularjs-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values) in order to know the different ways in which you can achieve it depending upon your data model.

Answer (score 1):

By the way ,you can take value on click

Angularjs code:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope){
 $scope.assetTypeList=[{id:1,checked:false},{id:2,checked:false},{id:3,checked:false},{id:4,checked:false}];
    $scope.fnChangeAssetType=function(val){
      alert(val.id);
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller='myctrl'>
    <ul class="ul-list-10">
     <li ng-repeat="assetType in assetTypeList">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="assetType.checked" ng-click="fnChangeAssetType(assetType)" value="{{assetType.id}}" />
         {{assetType.id}}
     </li>
 </ul>
    </div>
```

jsFiddle For solution:http://jsfiddle.net/kLrvs4ty/1/