# AngularJS: How $Scope function can return another function

Tags: angularjs

i am learning angular. so reading many post and article for angular. this time i do not understand a particular area in code.
code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26741697/728750

```
<label ng-repeat="fruitName in ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'naartjie']">
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    ng-model="fruitsGetterSetterGenerator(fruitName)" 
    ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"
  > {{fruitName}}
</label>

$scope.fruits = ['apple', 'pear']; // pre checked

$scope.fruitsGetterSetterGenerator = function(fruitName){
    return function myGetterSetter(nowHasFruit){
        if (nowHasFruit !== undefined){
            // setter
            fruitIndex = $scope.fruits.indexOf(fruit);
            didHaveFruit = (fruitIndex !== -1);
            mustAdd = (!didHaveFruit && nowHasFruit);
            mustDel = (didHaveFruit && !nowHasFruit);
            if (mustAdd){
                $scope.fruits.push(fruit);
            }
            if (mustDel){
                $scope.fruits.splice(fruitIndex, 1);
            }
        } else {
            //getter
            return $scope.user.fruits.indexOf(fruit) !== -1;
        }
    }
}
```

do not understand the above code.

the problem lies here. see the code below

```
$scope.fruitsGetterSetterGenerator = function(fruitName){
    return function myGetterSetter(nowHasFruit){}
}
```

**fruitsGetterSetterGenerator** is a function and it return another function from it **myGetterSetter** in it first line this kind of approach or pattern is not clear to me. please help me to understand. thanks

Comment: Function returns something, that can be - object, function -- whats the problem?

Comment: `ng-model` expects an object but here `ng-model="fruitsGetterSetterGenerator(fruitName)"` we have function invocation that will return an object. So it is time to tell AngularJS that it should execute our function so it will have access to returned object.

Comment: The answer and the documentation it links to explain the approach. I'm not sure what else you need to know.

Comment: when the function myGetterSetter() will be called and who will call it?

Comment: anyone can help me to understand the posted code.