# Checkboxes list in Angular 1.5 with one name/model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

How to set dynamically list of checkboxes. It seems that what worked in older versions [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-to-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs) doesn't work in angular 1.5.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cars[item.id]"  ng-value="{{item.id}}" ng-checked="item.checked == '1'"> {{item.car}}
</div>
$scope.items = [{id:'1', car:'opel', checked:'1'},
               {id:'2', car:'fiat', checked:'1'},
               {id:'3', car:'ford', checked:'0'}];
```

This loop doesn't work correctly, I didn't get ng-model="cars[1]", ng-model="cars[2]", etc but is ng-model="cars[item.id]"

What I need is dynamically  generate list of checkboxes and receive actual state of checked checkboxes:

```
cars = $scope.cars; //this should return [1, 2]
```

Comment: Did you try this ? -     <div ng-repeat="item in items">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="cars[{{item.id}}]"  ng-value="{{item.id}}" ng-checked="item.checked == '1'"> {{item.car}}
    </div>

Comment: This also don't work