# How to disable check box per day and fetch the selected values using Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have one table where some dynamic drop down list is present for 7 days. I have also `+` button implementation which can create more row dynamically for a day.

For each row I have check box. Here I need for each day user can only check up-to two check box and other will remain disable.

In my case after checked from 2 check box from total table other are becoming disable but here I need to disable per day.

My all working code is present inside: [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/yq0Ut11Pw8V5JrfqoUGD?p=preview).

There you can find one `Edit` button; I need when user will click on edit button the stored data (clicked on store button) will again set on the required field with check box.

My all code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/yq0Ut11Pw8V5JrfqoUGD?p=preview).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? "i need to disable per day", when does it have to be disabled?

Comment: let me to explain again.Go to that plunkr code.Suppose user has selected max two check box for `monday` and for that monday user can not selected more check box it will remain disable.Same for the all day.right not its happening in whole table.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you require, it's a little hard to understand your question:

So instead of your disabled function:

```
  $scope.chk =[];
  $scope.isDisabled = function(dayName) {
    var count = 0;
    if ($scope.chk[dayName]) {
      for (var prop in $scope.chk[dayName]) {
        if ($scope.chk[dayName][prop]) count++;
      }
    }
    return count++ === 2;
  };
```

Note the line above the disabled function. And then your html:

```
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" 
           name="{{d.day_name}}" 
           value="true"
           ng_model="chk[d.day_name][$index]"
           ng-checked="answerIsSelected($parent.$index, $index)"
           ng-click="toggleAnswerSelected($parent.$index, $index)"
           ng-disabled="isDisabled('{{d.day_name}}')" /> 
    </td>
```

Plunk here: [Plunky McPlunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/wDF8WN?p=preview)

Seems to do as you ask, disable after 2 goes.

Check this additional link: [More insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-to-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs)

For further info