# How do I adapt existing decorator directive in AngularJS to select all checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I've been using a decorator directive to create a checkbox list that is based on this previous answer:
[How do I bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-to-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs/14519881#14519881)

However, I want to add a "top-level" checkbox that toggles the selection of all checkboxes.

Is there a way to customise this directive to achieve this?

EDIT (I've included stripped down version of my code):

```
(function ()
{
    var app = angular.module('editFormApp', ['centralCommunicationModule']);


    app.directive('editForm', ['sharedProjectService', function (sharedProjectService) {
            return {
                restrict: 'A',

                controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', 'centralCommunicationService', function ($scope, $http, $filter, centralCommunicationService) {

                    $scope.checked_custGroupMembers = [];

                    $scope.reschedule = {};

                    // get reschedule object from server via service when id changes
                    $scope.$watch(function () { return sharedProjectService.rescheduleId }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
                    if (newVal != '') {
                        $scope.rescheduleId = newVal;                       

                        $http.get('/Reschedule/Get/', { params: { id: $scope.rescheduleId } }).success(function (data) {
                            var reschedule = angular.fromJson(data);

                            $scope.reschedule = reschedule;

                        });
                    }
                });

                }],

                templateUrl: '/Forms/_AddEditForm'  // MVC controller returning PartialView("~/Views/AngularTemplates/_AddEditForm.cshtml", model);
            };
    }]);
}



// declare directive in html
<div edit-form></div>

// template _AddEditForm.cshtml snippet below

<div ng-repeat="circulationMember in reschedule.CustGroupCirculationMembers">
    <label>
        <input name="custGroupMembers" type='checkbox' value="{{circulationMember.FullName}}" check-list='checked_custGroupMembers' id="{{circulationMember.Id}}" /> {{circulationMember.FullName}}
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try do something like this, it's hard to answer completely without seeing some code

```
angular.module('change this to your module').config(function($provide) {

  'use strict';

  $provide.decorator('checkList', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    var directive = $delegate[0];
    directive.link = function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      var invokes = angular.module('checklist')._invokeQueue,
          result = [];
      for(var i=0; i<invokes.length; i++) {
          if(invokes[i][1] == "directive") {
              result.push(invokes[i][2][0]);
          }
      }

      for(var j=0; j<result.length; j++) {
        // change checked for each one here
      }

      var handler = function(setup) {
        var checked = elem.prop('checked');
        var index = scope.list.indexOf(scope.value);
        if (checked && index == -1) {
          if (setup) elem.prop('checked', false);
          else scope.list.push(scope.value);
        } else if (!checked && index != -1) {
          if (setup) elem.prop('checked', true);
          else scope.list.splice(index, 1);
        }
      };

      var setupHandler = handler.bind(null, true);
      var changeHandler = handler.bind(null, false);

      elem.bind('change', function() {
        scope.$apply(changeHandler);
      });

      scope.$watch('list', setupHandler, true);

    };

    return $delegate;

  }]);

});
```

Comment: Please could you take a look at my edits above? I'm not familar with $provide but does your code replace the original decorator directive or are you referencing it somehow? Unfortunately am not expert in Angular so if possible would appreciate any comments in the code as to what each bit does and any feedback on how it might work with my code snippets. Thanks for your help.