# Why is my angular script running an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to do is check three boxes via event click upon page load with the use of for loop. What happens is it runs an infinite loop then the page hangs. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="ngToggle">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="dean" ng-click="btnChange($event, values, 1)" id="check-1" name="one" class="here" >
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="armada" ng-click="btnChange($event, values, 2)" id="check-2" name="one" class="here" >
        <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="armada" ng-click="btnChange($event, values, 2)" id="check-3" name="one" class="here" >
        <!--<p ng-repeat="btn in btns">-->
        <!--  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="btn.bool" class="here" > {{ btn.value }}-->
        <!--</p>-->
        {{btn  }}
        {{values  }}
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('ngToggle', [])
            .controller('AppCtrl',['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
            $scope.btns = [{}, {}, {}];
            $scope.values = [];
            $scope.btnChange = function(event, model, val){
              _this = angular.element(event.target);
              x = _this.prop("checked");
              if(x){
                model.push(val);
              }else{
                index = model.indexOf(val);
                model.splice(index, 1);
              }
            };
            ids = [1, 2, 3];

            $timeout(function() {
              for(x=0;x<ids.length;x++){
             angular.element("#check-"+ids[x]).trigger("click");
              }
        }, 1000);
        }]);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/7DpCvkKLlKhRc3YwFTq0?p=info

**PS**

If you comment or removed the angular.element trigger this will not occur. If someone can provide a code that will trigger the click events on the checkboxes via loop. **THEN IT WILL BE GREAT**

Comment: This is not how thing works in angular; Check this answer on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-to-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs.

Comment: The post did not really answer my question. What I want is my checkboxes to be clicked via trigger upon page load

Comment: NO you do not want that, you want your checkboxes to be checked on loading, for this you just need to set the model value on the controller and angular will map it to the checkbox.

Comment: At its core, it does answer the question – you don't *need* to trigger clicks because Angular handles that for you when the data binding is done properly.

Comment: The thing is.. The ng-click function will not trigger and I want to tigger it via loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the Angular way by setting default values to your checkboxes:

As you use [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel), in your controller, just set `dean` and `armada` to `true`.

---

**UPDATE:**

I've nevertheless debugged your JS. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/OzATQIlRWKFzjB36pDEL?p=preview) is a plunker of your function working. I've used y in the loop (x was already defined) and change a bit the condition of looping.

Anyway, I would recommend you to do with Angular... :-)

Comment: The thing with your suggestion is.. The ng-click function will not trigger and I want to tigger it via loop

Comment: Updated my answer. I provide a plunker that should correct your JS function :)

Comment: Awesome! you rock! You're the only one who was able to solve my tricky question/problem. So what exactly happened  here? Seems like you just added "var"

Comment: Your `x` was defined to `_this.prop("checked");`, it makes the condition of the loop infinite. So I just created a variable for the loop (`y`) to replace it (and change a bit the break condition of your loop)!
Glad I helped! :-)

Comment: Hi, I just added var and it worked.. May I know what var has to do within the for loop? Without var, it will just do the infinite loop again