# How to bind single checkbox value with AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, data-binding

I have checked question [How to bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-to-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs). But this question explains list of arrays and best ways to handle it in Angular controller.

```
<input type='checkbox' name="filter" checked>
```

How can we bind value to checkbox to have value as modal 0 when unchecked and 1 when checked? What should be in HTML and Controller?

```
$scope.filter = 0;
```

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/rGK1fbYHQinH7OoO6Qqm?p=preview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.filter = 0;//or 1
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an modified example based on the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D)

**Controller**

```
angular.module('checkboxExample', [])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.checkboxModel = 0; //Set checkbox to unchecked
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0">
```

Comment: Good copy of my answer.

Comment: Sorry I did not saw it... I was writing my answer

Answer (score 0):

Angular has provided ng-true-value & ng-false-value directives to fullfill your requirement. Through it you can associate true/false values with checkbox and same will be using by model as well.

### You can try below code

```
<div ng-controller="ValidateCtrl">
    Check Value: <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" ng-model="checkBoxModel"/>
</div>

Controller
---------
function ValidateCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.checkBoxModel = '1';
};
```

So initially checkbox will be checked.