# How to assign reassign checkbox ng-model on ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Please help me out. I have a checkboxes with models defined. I am displaying checkboxes and using the model to set if the checkbox is selected or not. Below is the code for setting the ng-model.

```
LoadValues(obj) {

  vm.index = false;
  vm.create = false;
  vm.edit = false;
  vm.delete = false;
  vm.other = false;

  var pList = obj.Functions;
  var currentModule = obj.Name;

  for (var i = 0; i < pList.length; i++) {

    var currentItem = pList[i];
    console.log(currentItem)

    if (currentItem.search("Index") > 0) {
      vm.index = true;
      console.log(vm.index);
    } else if (currentItem.search("Create") > 0) {
      vm.create = true;
    } else if (currentItem.search("Edit") > 0) {
      vm.edit = true;
    } else if (currentItem.search("Delete") > 0) {
      vm.delete = true;
    } else if (currentItem.search("Other") > 0) {
      vm.other = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the check boxes.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in list">
    <td>
      {{item.Name}}
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Index" type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.index" ng-click="EditRole(Right,item.Module,'Index')">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Create" type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.create" ng-click="EditRole(item.Role,'Create')">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Edit" type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.edit" ng-click="EditRole(item.Role,item.Module,'Edit')">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Delete" type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.delete" ng-click="EditRole(item.Role,item.Module,'Delete')">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="Other" type="checkbox" ng-model="vm.other" ng-click="EditRole(item.Role,item.Module,'Other')">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

The problem is it assigns the same ng-model to all the items in the list. I have tried to find solutions nothing is helping. Your help would be very much appreciated.

i am reading my data from a json file. Below is some example data:

```
    [ 
{"Role":"Staff","Admins":[{"Name":"Username","userRights":["UserEdit","UserCreate"]
    }]
```

Comment: Use `ng-model="item.index"`, `item.create`, `item.edit` etc.

Comment: This answer might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/14516885/1599191

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to use ng-model on a checkbox is to pass it an abject. The code below converts an array of items into an object for the checkboxes.

I created a variable called `$scope.userRights` which contains all of the available options.

In the HTML we loop though each field displaying its name and then loop though all of the `userRights`.

The submit button then converts the object back into the array format we received.

HTML

```
<div ng:controller="MainCtrl">
  <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>

  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="field in fields">
      <td ng-bind="field.Name"></td>

      <td ng-repeat="right in userRights">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="field.userRights[right]" /> {{right}} 
        </label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <pre ng-bind="fields | json"></pre>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.userRights = ["UserEdit","UserCreate","UserSomethingElse"];

  $scope.fields = [
    {"Name":"Username","userRights":["UserEdit","UserCreate"]},
    {"Name":"Password","userRights":["UserEdit"]}
  ];

  // Convert array to object
  $scope.fields.forEach(function(field) {
    var res = {};
    field.userRights.forEach(function(right) {
     res[right] = true;
    });
    field.userRights = res;
  });

  function objectValues(obj) {
    var res = [];
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    for (var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
      if (obj[keys[i]]) res.push(keys[i]);
    }
    return res;
  }

  // Convert object to array
  $scope.submit = function() {
    $scope.fields.forEach(function(field) {
      field.userRights = objectValues(field.userRights);
    });
  };
});
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLCx289fSMhosBv2J7RZ?p=preview)

Comment: Is it possible to do this without the button. Because the intention is to have all that performed on page load.

Comment: Check my updated answer. The button simply converts the object structure when the user is finished. Here's a working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/cLCx289fSMhosBv2J7RZ?p=preview) where you can see the structure on screen

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model has to be like so:

```
ng-model="item.index"
```

And then in your controller inside the for loop:

```
current_item.index = true;
```

Hope it helps =)

Comment: I am reading my data from a json file. So the currentItem is from a file. Sorry i didnt specify that.