# ng-model for dynamic loaded items

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, arrays, checkbox

I've got a list with some items (for example cars) which is dynamic, so it hasn't got a fixed length. When I load this list it looks like this:

```
itemList = [
    { id: 0, name: 'bmw' },
    { id: 1, name: 'audi' },
    { id: 3, name: 'vw' },
    { id: 4, name: 'subaru' },
    { id: 5, name: 'mercedes' }
];
```

After that, I loop this list in an ng-repeat loop and create some checkboxes, so I can select items:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label>{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```

Now I have a user object. This object has an array "cars" within, where I would like push all the selected cars and remove it if I deselect it. My object looks like this:

```
userObj = [
    { 
      name: 'user1', 
      cars: [] 
    }
];
```

So when I select a car, it should be pushed into the array `cars` in my user object and also removed if I deselect it. I know I have to do this with `ng-change` and this wouldn't be my real problem. My problem is the `ng-model` for the checkbox. I don't know how to do it the best. I can't use the same ng-model for every list this is pretty logical. What would be the best way? Didn't find any solution on the internet.

Comment: afaik, ngModel binds via reference as stated in the [(docs)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange), so if you reassign whatever value is bound via ng-model with a new reference, it should update and adjust the value it references appropriately.

Comment: Does this answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-to-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could update specific user's `cars` array, on `change` of `checkbox` of each item `itemList` like below.

**Markup**

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" ng-change="itemChange(user)">
    <label>{{item.name}}</label>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.itemChange = function(user){
   var selectedCarsIds = $scope.itemList.filter((i) => i.checked).map(item => item.id)
   //update cars array for specific user
   user.cars = selectedCarsIds;
}
```

Comment: @MrBuggy Pleasure to know that, Thanks :)