# Angular formly - Checkbox model values template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I have a small form that has default values for some checkboxes for example, there is an person model, when the checkbox "dog" in the form generated by formly is clicked it will add to an array of "pets" the string of dog that forms part of the person model. How can I achieve this with formly?

```
{
     key: "dog",
     type: "checkbox",
     templateOptions: {
          ???
     }
}
```

Form example:

```
Person name: Joe
Pets:
[x] dog
```

This will set the model to:

```
 {
      "name": "Joe"
      "pets": [ "dog" ]
 }
```

Comment: please provide some more details about questions.

Comment: Added more info, hope it helps.

Comment: The similar problem was solved in that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14514461/2275775

The answer is long, popular and well-checked, so creating new one is not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

@veg, this question is for angular formly, not angular.  It's different.  Significantly so.

In your initialization:

```
vm.model = { //initialize a model with a pets property holding an empty array.
  pets: []
}
```

In your field model:

```
{
   key: 'dog',
   type: 'checkbox',
   templateOptions: {
      label: 'dog',
      onChange: function($viewValue, $modelValue, $scope) {
        if($modelValue) $scope.model.pets.push('dog'); //if it's true--add it
        else { //need to remove it from the array
           var index = $scope.model.pets.indexOf('dog'); //get the index
           $scope.model.pets.slice(index, index+1); //remove it from the array
        }
      }
   },
}
```