# Angularjs get dynamic data from checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to get dynamic data from checkbox in angularjs? I trying to use below code but getting error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="procForAcnts in procForAcnt">
                    <td>{{procForAcnts[0]}}</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="procNums[$index]" ng-change="test()" value="{{procForAcnts[2]}}"> {{procForAcnts[4]}}</td>
                    <td>{{procForAcnts[3]}}</td>
                    <td>{{procForAcnts[1]}}</td>
                    <td>{{procForAcnts[5]}}</td>
                    <td>{{procForAcnts[2]}}.00</td>
                    <td><center>--</center></td>
                    <td>{{procForAcnts[7]}}</td>
                    </tr>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.test = function() {
var len= $scope.procForAcnt.length;
alert(len); //working
for(i=0; i<len; i++){
alert($scope.procNums[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Check that your variable `procForAcnts` is defined

Comment: can you provide sample data for "procForAcnt"

Answer (score 0):

Although, you have not posted complete code here. All I can suggest you is to send parameter to your test method.

Replace:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="procNums[$index]" ng-change="test()" value="{{procForAcnts[2]}}"> {{procForAcnts[4]}}</td>
```

With:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="procNums[$index]" ng-change="test(procNums[$index])" value="{{procForAcnts[2]}}"> {{procForAcnts[4]}}</td>
```

Then receive the value in your test method as a parameter:

```
$scope.test = function(selectedValue) {
   alert(selectedValue);
};
```

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: thanks, but got the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-do-i-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs

Comment: Yeah, that is surely better explained. It all depends on the complexity of your design. All the best!