# How to select two or more checkbox based on the value in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

How to select two or more checkbox based on the value in angularjs?

[Plunker reference](http://plnkr.co/edit/3gH2rv0Uk2zZbDd6BZLv?p=preview)

- In plunker there are four `checkbox` inputs each of one `values` is different but `ng-model` is same for four inputs, so if I checked `Moral Ethics` checkbox this value is need to be save in api.
- What I exactly looking is, as now if I clicked any of one checkbox in plunker all the checkbox is checked bcoz of the same `ng-model`. actually we have mentioned `ng-model` as array in backend, so if click any of two checkbox that checked values only to be save in backend...

**For Example:** in plunker I want to click `Moral Ethics` checkbox and `Social network` these two values only  need to checked and it should saved as a array json data in backend.

This [jsbin link](http://output.jsbin.com/ImAqUC/1/) is exactly what we want. We have tried many ways but unable to find the solution. So please check and update my plunker as well to know the exact solution.

```js
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.questions = [{
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Religion & Culture",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },

    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Moral Ethics",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Environment & Health",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Environment & Health",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Religion & Culture",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Religion & Culture",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Moral Ethics",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="Moral Ethics" data-ng-model="category" value="Moral Ethics" ><span>Moral Ethics</span></label></div>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="green"><input type="checkbox" name="culture" data-ng-model="category" value="culture" ><span>Religion & Culture</span></label></div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="green"><input type="checkbox" name="Social network" data-ng-model="category" value="Social network" ><span>Social network</span></label></div>


    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label class="green"><input type="checkbox" name="Environment logic" data-ng-model="category" value="Environment logic" ><span>Environment logic</span></label></div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The answer you quoted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-do-i-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs is a nice solution, why don't you do the same?

Comment: @cyril Gandon I am looking to do this in `form` but they are used `ng-repeat="fruitName in fruits"` and all, i am little bit confused on that solution, so can you please update my plunker as well to know the solution please....

Comment: When you have api ? Is there any reason to hardcode the checkboxes ?

Comment: @gururaj in my portal while user is signing up, they need to fill the all details in a form ... then the user must to need to select two categories  while they filling up the details so that only i have used the checkbox ... i have given the plunker on above so please look that and help me..thanks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code snippet that behaves like you want. It actually keeps a seperate array of selected items and maintains it every time you check/uncheck something.

```js
function MyCntrl($scope) {
   $scope.toggleSelection = function toggleSelection(item) {
    var idx = $scope.selection.indexOf(item);

    // is currently selected
    if (idx > -1) {
      $scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  
    // is newly selected
    else {
      $scope.selection.push(item);
    }
  };

  $scope.selection = [];

  $scope.items = ["Moral Ethics", "Religion & Culture", "Social network", "Environment logic"];
  $scope.questions = [{
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Religion & Culture",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },

    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Moral Ethics",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Environment & Health",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Environment & Health",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Religion & Culture",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Religion & Culture",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5863d3aaacaeddc00663bc07",
      "user": {
        "_id": "58072aba0f82a61823c434df",
        "displayName": "Table 1",
        "dob": "2016-12-22T18:30:00.000Z",
        "location": "chennai",
        "religion": "hindu",
        "roles": [
          "admin"
        ],
        "profileImageURL": "./modules/users/client/img/profile/uploads/ac4fbab396c2f725ed5211524f171136"
      },

      "friend_tag": [],
      "emotion": "Confused",
      "category": "Moral Ethics",
      "content": "mani",
      "title": "Who Is the best Player?",
      "created": "2016-12-28T15:00:58.777Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form ng-controller="MyCntrl">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label ng-repeat="item in items" style="display: block">
        <input type="checkbox" name="selectedItems[]" data-ng-model="category" value="{{item}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(item) > -1" ng-click="toggleSelection(item)"><span>{{item}}</span></label>
   </div>
  
    <pre style="margin-top: 30px">{{selection}}</pre>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer if i used your above answer in my portal it's saved like `"category": ["true"],` i want to save values only not like true (or) false.... please check my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WOQpbclGctnarNoW1gKc?p=preview).... in my module i have coded like :- category: [{
    type: String,
    default: '',
    required: 'Select Atleast Two Category',
    trim: true
  }],   please check and update...thanks

Comment: so this plunker of your's look good then [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WOQpbclGctnarNoW1gKc?p=preview)