# how to get multiple selected checkbox id in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
 <label ng-repeat="option in userlist">
    <input type="checkbox" id="{{option.EntityID}}"/>
        {{option.Name}} <br>
 </label>
```

How to get multiple selected checkbox id in angularjs array ??

Comment: What is your problem, what in your posted snipped doesn't work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I bind to list of checkbox values with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-do-i-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

```
<label ng-repeat="option in userlist">
  <input type="checkbox" 
    name="{{option.EntityID}}" 
    id="{{option.EntityID}}" 
    ng-model="option.value">{{option.Name}}<br>
</label>
```

assuming you can build your data like this

```
$scope.userlist = [{
  EntityID: 1,
  Name: 'AAA',
  value: false
}, {
  EntityID: 2,
  key: 'BBB',
  value: false
}];
```

Just use map and get the list of IDs

```
var selectedIdList = $scope.userlist.filter(function(object) {
  return object.value;
}).map(function(tag) {
  return object.EntityID;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="usersavailable" class="on-sel-hide browser-default" ng-model="selectedusers1" size="3" multiple>
    <option ng-repeat="option in userlist" value="{{option.user_id}}">{{option.first_name}} {{option.last_name}}</option>  
     </select>
```

In controller use:

```
var selectedUsers     = $scope.selectedusers1;
```