# Does ag-grid have an api to filter multiple checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, filtering, ag-grid

I'm using angularjs and have a list of checkboxes that I need to able to filter my ag-grid on.

This works fine using radio buttons and calling api.setQuickFilter with the individual value. However, I'm not seeing a way to allow for multiple 'filters' (i.e. checkbox values stored in an array) to function with setQuickFilter.  Is there another method I should be using to accomplish this?

Example: 
[checkbox] Apple
[checkbox] Bee
[checkbox] Cheerios

Checking box Apple and Cheerios at the same time should return a grid filtered to only show rows that contain the word "Apple" OR "Cheerios".

Answer (score 4):

Per ag-grid support, this is not possible out of the box - which contradicts some of the examples (albeit, non-working) found on ag-grid's documentation page (see https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/#.)  They did suggest writing a custom function to accomplish this.  However, I was able to get it to work through another method.

**Solution:** I was able to filter out the selections by writing a function within the controller (that searches through the grid array and compares elements) to recreate the grid data.  Then calls setRowData with the new filtered array.  I made the checkboxes call this function to add/remove the displayed rows.

Here's what the code looks like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="checkboxFilter" ng-repeat="filterItemName in filterItem">
  <input type="checkbox" name="selectedCap[]" value="{{filterItemName}}" ng-checked="selection.indexOf(filterItemName) > -1" ng-click="$ctrl.chartData(filterItemName)" /> {{filterItemName}}
</div>
```

**js**

```
//defined elsewhere (i.e. $onLoad):
this.$scope.filterItem = gridFilterArray; //(checkbox items)
this.$scope.selection = [];


chartData(value){

//****this portion from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-do-i-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs?rq=1 *****
   let idx = this.$scope.selection.indexOf(value);

   // Is currently selected
   if (idx > -1) {
     this.$scope.selection.splice(idx, 1);
   }

   // Is newly selected
   else {
     this.$scope.selection.push(value);
   }
//******end

   let filteredArray = [];

   //create new array of data to display based on filtered checkboxes
   for(let x = 0; x < this.arrayData.length; x++) {
     for(let y = 0; y < this.$scope.selection.length; y++) {
       if (this.$scope.selection[y] === this.arrayData[x].fieldToCheck)
         filteredArray.push(this.arrayData[x]);
     }
   }

   if(this.$scope.selection.length === 0)
     this.$scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.arrayData);
   else
     this.$scope.gridOptions.api.setRowData(filteredArray);
}
```

Comment: Clever idea. It is a shame that I just saw it right after finishing my custom filter...