# How to populate list of checkbox values with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to build a quiz application in angular js with serverside for that i have 2 type of choices:

1. Multiple options for one question `(input-checkbox)`.    `"dataType": 3,`
2. Single option
   for one question. `(input-radio)`    `"dataType": 2,`

I am trying to populate stored answer for multiple `checkbox` questions in this case `storedAnswer` is an array, whereas `storedAnswer` is an integer value for `input radio`

**Note:** `storedAnswer` array contains the `option.questionChoiceValue`'s

My question is how can i populate array value as checked for multiple choice (`checkbox`) question:

This is my HTML code:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in data.questionData">

    <span name="multiSelectCheckBox" ng-if="question.dataType == 3">
        <div ng-repeat="option in question.choices " class="">
            <label for="mul_{{option.questionChoiceValue}}_ques{{option.questionId}}">
                <span ng-repeat="stAns in question.storedAnswer"
                      ng-if="stAns == option.questionChoiceValue">
                    <input id="mul_{{option.questionChoiceValue}}_ques{{option.questionId}}" 
                        type="checkbox"
                        ng-model="question.storedAnswer"
                        ng-change="onSelect(question, option);" /> 
                      {{option.questionChoiceText}}
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </span>

    <span name="multiSelectRadio" ng-if="question.dataType == 2">
        <div ng-repeat="option in question.choices  " class="">
            <label for="sin_{{option.questionChoiceValue}}_ques{{option.questionId}}">

                <input type="radio" id="sin_{{option.questionChoiceValue}}_ques{{option.questionId}}" 
                    ng-model="question.storedAnswer" 
                    value="{{option.questionChoiceValue | number}}"
                    name="que_ques{{option.questionId}}"
                    ng-change="onSelect(question, option);" />
                  {{option.questionChoiceText}}                 
            </label>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

I have an object like this:

```
[
    {
        "marked": "false",
        "questionId": "7d00a35ddb6313004f3bdde748961969",
        "helpText": "",
        "answered": "true",
        "storedAnswer": [
            1,
            5
        ],
        "questionSno": 1,
        "dataType": 3,
        "choices": [
            {
                "questionId": "7d00a35ddb6313004f3bdde748961969",
                "questionChoiceValue": 5,
                "questionChoiceText": "Float, long double"
            },
            {
                "questionId": "7d00a35ddb6313004f3bdde748961969",
                "questionChoiceValue": 4,
                "questionChoiceText": "Float"
            },
            {
                "questionId": "7d00a35ddb6313004f3bdde748961969",
                "questionChoiceValue": 3,
                "questionChoiceText": "float, double, long double"
            },
            {
                "questionId": "7d00a35ddb6313004f3bdde748961969",
                "questionChoiceValue": 2,
                "questionChoiceText": "long double, short int"
            },
            {
                "questionId": "7d00a35ddb6313004f3bdde748961969",
                "questionChoiceValue": 1,
                "questionChoiceText": "short int, double, long int, float"
            }
        ],
        "questionText": "In C, what are the various types of real data type (floating point data type)?",
        "selected": "false"
    },
    {
        "marked": "false",
        "questionId": "93e5c5e5db6713004f3bdde748961957",
        "helpText": "",
        "answered": "false",
        "storedAnswer": 1,
        "questionSno": 3,
        "dataType": 2,
        "choices": [
            {
                "questionId": "93e5c5e5db6713004f3bdde748961957",
                "questionChoiceValue": 3,
                "questionChoiceText": "May be"
            },
            {
                "questionId": "93e5c5e5db6713004f3bdde748961957",
                "questionChoiceValue": 2,
                "questionChoiceText": "False"
            },
            {
                "questionId": "93e5c5e5db6713004f3bdde748961957",
                "questionChoiceValue": 1,
                "questionChoiceText": "True"
            }
        ],
        "questionText": "A macro can execute faster than a function.",
        "selected": "false"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be using ng-checked instead of ng-model for your radio. Like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="sin_{{option.questionChoiceValue}}_ques{{option.questionId}}"
       ng-checked="question.storedAnswer"
       value="{{option.questionChoiceValue | number}}"
       name="que_ques{{option.questionId}}"
       ng-change="onSelect(question, option);" />
```

Comment: radio is working fine i have a problem with checkboxes because storedAnswer is an array

Comment: So you're asking how to mark the radios as selected on initialization based on the storedAnswers array?

Comment: In order to work, the `ng-change` directive needs the `ng-model` directive and the `ng-checked` directive doesn' t play nice with the `ng-model` directive.