# Get selected values of checkbox group Angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My goal is to have a set of checkboxes where users will make selections and when they hit the submit button, I'll print to the console what they chose.

My problem is that I can't seem to fetch the data from the checkbox group in my Javascript. I attempted to create a minimal reproducible example, but I can't even get the `ng-repeat` working on jsfiddle :-S [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k9t3zvwc/1/)

I want to use `ng-repeat` to create a bunch of checkboxes

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="game in games">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="answers.games" value="{{game.game_id}}">{{game.game}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

where on the javascript side I have something like

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('playController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http){
        getWeeks();

        $scope.games = [
        {game_id: 1, game: "Game 1"},
        {game_id: 2, game: "Game 2"},
        {game_id: 3, game: "Game 3"}
        ]

        $scope.score_submission = function(){
            console.log($scope.answers)
        }
    })
})();
```

But, the checkboxes don't bind to `$scope.answers` the way I thought they would, instead, `$scope.answers` remains undefined. What I'd like to get back is an array of the `game_id` values that were checked.

Comment: My first question would be, why are you using a deprecated library instead of using Angular?

Comment: Because I'd used it before and I was going to avoid having to learn too much new stuff.

Comment: if you want you can try alternate approach. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514461/how-do-i-bind-to-list-of-checkbox-values-with-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="game in games">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[game.id]"> {{game.game}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
$scope.selected = {};
```

Comment: Follow-up, I noticed that if I check a box and then uncheck it, it's not removed from $scope.selected - what do I need to do to enable that behavior?

Comment: When a checkbox is unchecked. The `ng-model` directive sets the property to `false`. It does not delete it. You can set it to another value with the `ng-false-value` directive. If you want you can use the `ng-change` directive to delete the property.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach might be...

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="game in games">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="game.isSelected"> {{game.game}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your controller:

```
    $scope.score_submission = function(){
        $scope.answers = [];
        for(var i=0; i < $scope.games.length) {
            if($scope.games[i].isSelected) $scope.answers.push($scope.games[i].game_id);
        }
    }
```

The only small downside of this solution is that you manipulate $scope.games - but I don't see a big disadvantage here as long as the lists are not too big.